# map function for objects (instead of arrays)

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, map-function

I have an object:

```
myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
```

I am looking for a native method, similar to `Array.prototype.map` that would be used as follows:

```
newObject = myObject.map(function (value, label) {
    return value * value;
});

// newObject is now { 'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 9 }
```

Does JavaScript have such a `map` function for objects? (I want this for Node.JS, so I don't care about cross-browser issues.)

Comment: Most answers use `Object.keys`, which doesn't have any well-defined order. That can be problematic, I suggest using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead.

Comment: @Oriol are you sure about that? According to the MDN web docs, the ordering of array elements is consistent between `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: @Bart The order of `Object.keys` is implementation-dependent. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/1529630

Comment: @Oriol You're not supposed to rely on the order of keys in objects anyway, so its kinda irrelevant to the question - since he never specified that the order mattered to him. And if order mattered to him, he shouldn't be using an object at all anyway.

Comment: someone please put some of these solutions in an npm package, with tests please

Answer (score 2538, accepted):

There is no native `map` to the `Object` object, but how about this:

```js
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key, index) {
  myObject[key] *= 2;
});

console.log(myObject);
// => { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }
```

But you could easily iterate over an object using `for ... in`:

```js
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myObject[key] *= 2;
  }
}

console.log(myObject);
// { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }
```

## Update

A lot of people are mentioning that the previous methods do not return a new object, but rather operate on the object itself. For that matter I wanted to add another solution that returns a new object and leaves the original object as it is:

```js
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

// returns a new object with the values at each key mapped using mapFn(value)
function objectMap(object, mapFn) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(result, key) {
    result[key] = mapFn(object[key])
    return result
  }, {})
}

var newObject = objectMap(myObject, function(value) {
  return value * 2
})

console.log(newObject);
// => { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }

console.log(myObject);
// => { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
```

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) reduces an array to a single value by somewhat merging the previous value with the current. The chain is initialized by an empty object `{}`. On every iteration a new key of `myObject` is added with twice the key as the value.

## Update

With new ES6 features, there is a more elegant way to express `objectMap`.

```js
const objectMap = (obj, fn) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      ([k, v], i) => [k, fn(v, k, i)]
    )
  )
  
const myObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

console.log(objectMap(myObject, v => 2 * v))
```

Comment: it also doesn't preserve the semantics of `Array.map`, which is supposed to return an array.

Comment: I've updated my answer - it seems (on re-reading the question) that the OP wants a _new_ object with the same keys, where the values were mutated with the supplied function, and not to modify the original object in place.

Comment: @Alnitak You're correct. But all you'd have to do to make this return an array is do `return mbObject[value] * 2;` inside the map callback. That way you don't modify the original object (blegh) and you get a nice new array with your modified data.

Comment: @KhalilRavanna I think you've misread the code here - this answer isn't using `map` correctly because it isn't doing a `return` - it's abusing `map` as if it were a `forEach` call.  If he actually _did_ `return myObject[value] * 2` then the result would be an _array_ containing the original values doubled, instead of an _object_ containing the original keys with doubled values, the latter clearly being what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Alnitak Right. To clarify, I was just addressing your original comment that this answer wasn't preserving the normal function of the `map` function. I wasn't addressing the fact that doing so would not answer OP's question. Consider my response a tangent from the original thread of question by OP. ;)

Comment: @KhalilRavanna to clarify, what I meant (but omitted to say explicitly) is that it doesn't return a _new_ array ;-)

Comment: I agree with Alnitak. The use of `map` here is pointless when `forEach` would accomplish the same thing and make sense semantically. (And neither of your approaches produces a new object).

Comment: @Amberlamps your `.reduce` example is OK, but IMHO it still falls a long way short of the convenience of a `.map` for Objects, since your `.reduce` callback not only has to match the way that `.reduce` works, but also requires that `myObject` be available in the lexical scope.  The latter in particular makes it impossible to just pass a function reference in the callback, requiring an in-place anonymous function instead.

Comment: TBH I would have rather upvoted an answer that only (or originally) provided the second solution presented in this answer.  The first one works and is not necessarily wrong, but as others have stated, I don't like to see map being used that way.  When I see map, my mind is automatically thinking "immutable data structure"

Comment: How are we going to remove something from this map later?

Comment: This also gets a bit more terse with ES6.

`const newObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce((y, k) => Object.assign(y, {
 [k] : myObject[k] * myObject[k]
}), {});`

Comment: The first code should use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: this is not the functional programming way to do it, see my answer instead.

Comment: First of all, OP did not ask for a solution in functional solution. Secondly, my updated solution is functional.

Comment: your first solution is almost right, just add return

Comment: for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
    }

Comment: `.map` is not the appropriate method to use when you aren't going to use the resulting mapped array - if you want side-effects only, such as in your first code, you should most definitely use `forEach` instead.

Comment: There's no point in using map if you're not returning anything. When you switch to .keys() then also switch to .forEach()

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` is ES2019, not ES2015. Also, as others have said, I'd **highly** recommend replacing the `.map` in the first snippet with `forEach`, or something else more appropriate than `.map`

Comment: tried a typescript version of the last example: 
`const objectMap = <V, R>(
  obj: { [key: string]: V },
  fn: (value: V, key: string, index: number) => R
) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v], i) => [k, fn(v, k, i)]));
`

Answer (score 595):

How about a one-liner in JS **ES10 / ES2019** ?

Making use of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
let newObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, v * v]));
```

The same thing written as a function:

```js
function objMap(obj, func) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, func(v)]));
}

// To square each value you can call it like this:
let mappedObj = objMap(obj, (x) => x * x);
```

This function uses *recursion* to square nested objects as well:

```js
function objMap(obj, func) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => 
      [k, v === Object(v) ? objMap(v, func) : func(v)]
    )
  );
}

// To square each value you can call it like this:
let mappedObj = objMap(obj, (x) => x * x);
```

With **ES7 / ES2016** you can't use `Objects.fromEntries`, but you can achieve the same using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in combination with [spread operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [computed key names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) syntax:

```js
let newObj = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v * v})));
```

**ES6 / ES2015** Doesn't allow `Object.entries`, but you could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead:

```js
let newObj = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({[k]: obj[k] * obj[k]})));
```

ES6 also introduced [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops, which allow a more *imperative* style:

```js
let newObj = {}

for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  newObj[k] = v * v;
}
```

---

#### array.reduce()

Instead of `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.assign` you can also use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this:

```js
let newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((p, [k, v]) => ({ ...p, [k]: v * v }), {});
```

---

#### Inherited properties and the prototype chain:

In some rare situation you may need to map a *class-like* object which holds properties of an inherited object on its [prototype-chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). In such cases `Object.keys()` and `Object.entries()` won't work, because these functions do not include the prototype chain.

If you need to map *inherited* properties, you can use `for (key in myObj) {...}`.

Here is an example of such situation:

```js
const obj1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);  // One of multiple ways to inherit an object in JS.

// Here you see how the properties of obj1 sit on the 'prototype' of obj2
console.log(obj2)  // Prints: obj2.__proto__ = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

console.log(Object.keys(obj2));  // Prints: an empty Array.
console.log(Object.entries(obj2));  // Prints: an empty Array.

for (let key in obj2) {
  console.log(key);              // Prints: 'a', 'b', 'c'
}
```

However, please do me a favor and avoid *inheritance*. :-)

Comment: Beautiful but I got caught by the fact that `Object.keys` doesn't enumerate inherited properties.  I suggest you add a warning.

Comment: To shorten your answer, just use `Object.entries({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})`.

Comment: You have some typos (you refer to `(o, f)` as arguments but use `obj` in the body.

Comment: Hey, can you provide more information about why we should avoid inheritance? Some good article would be enough :)

Comment: `Object.entries({a: 1, b: 2}).map(([k, v]) => \`hello ${k} ${v}\`)` did the trick for me. Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: @DavidBraun If your using classes/inherited properties, or getter/setters, then you should  probably introduce a `copyFrom` function to those classes. There's no way to reliably clone anything but JSON parsable objects i.e. basic objects. That's been my experience after looking into it quite a bit (this goes for Lodash, Ramda clone as well)

Comment: The solution `Object.assign(...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v * v})))` does not work if `obj` is an empty object.  Change to: `Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v * v})))`.

Comment: The proposed `array.reduce()` implementation potentially has `O(n^2)` performance and I would recommend against it

Answer (score 151):

No native methods, but [lodash#mapValues](http://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) will do the job brilliantly

```
_.mapValues({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} , function(num) { return num * 3; });
// → { 'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9 }
```

Comment: There is no need to add an extra HTTP call and an extra library just for one function. In any case, this answer is now outdated and you can simply call `Object.entries({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})` to get an array.

Comment: Why is getting an array useful? The requirement was for a mapped object. Also there’s no implied HTTP call in using Lodash, a popular library essentially built for this type of thing, although there’s quite a few things that ES6 has precluded the necessity of using utility function libraries to some degree lately.

Comment: extra HTTP call to pull Lodash, I guess. If this is your only use case, indeed it's an overkill. Nonetheless, it makes sense to have this answer around for Lodash is such a widespread library.

Comment: not to mention you should actually use `_.map()` so you get the key as the second argument - as required by the OP.

Comment: `_.mapValues()` does also provide the key as the 2nd argument. Also `_.map()` would not work here as it only returns arrays, not objects: `_.map({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, n => n * 3) // [3, 6, 9]`

Answer (score 62):

It's pretty easy to write one:

```
Object.map = function(o, f, ctx) {
    ctx = ctx || this;
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
        result[k] = f.call(ctx, o[k], k, o); 
    });
    return result;
}
```

with example code:

```
> o = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
> r = Object.map(o, function(v, k, o) {
     return v * v;
  });
> r
{ a : 1, b: 4, c: 9 }
```

NB: this version also allows you to (optionally) set the `this` context for the callback, just like the `Array` method.

**EDIT** - changed to remove use of `Object.prototype`, to ensure that it doesn't clash with any existing property named `map` on the object.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Where did `c` come from? Was that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Ok. :) A comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179509/transforming-nested-objects-to-an-array#28179747) brought me here. I'll +1 this since the accepted answer is clearly misusing `map`, but I must say that modifying `Object.prototype` doesn't sit well with me, even if it isn't enumerable.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks.  IMHO in ES5 there's really no longer any reason *not* to modify `Object.prototype` other than the (theoretical) risk of collision with other methods.  FWIW, I can't understand how the other answer got as many votes as it has, it's completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah, collisions were what I had in mind, especially with a name like `map`.

Comment: @NickManning I've got a downvote roughly contemporary with your comment - if yours, an explanation would be nice.

Comment: @Alnitak wasn't me...I just upvoted your answer in fact

Comment: Modifying `Object.prototype` can cause issues with jQuery specifically Sizzle

Comment: @u01jmg3 it can, unless done safely as a non-enumerable property as shown in my code above

Comment: Extending objects you don't own is never advisable, regardless of ES version. One day ES will have `Object.prototype.map` with slightly different semantics. Good luck finding that bug.

Comment: @bfred.it  1)  if that were true it would have happened already - there's been ample opportunity to add it.   2)  these semantics are identical to `Array.prototype.map`    3)  _existing_ code using the function above wouldn't break, because it would override the hypothetical ES version.

Comment: This **already** doesn't work: `o = {map: true, image: false}`. You're _risking it_ just to write `o.map(fn)` instead of `map(o,fn)`

Comment: @bfred.it and I've updated accordingly.  I'd note that this only removes the risk of clashing with a property of that same name.  I checked, and there's so few properties on `Object` that I think if ES ever did acquire this method it would be `Object.map` rather than `Object.prototype.map` (and this is also consistent with the other "static" methods on `Object`)

Answer (score 28):

This is really annoying, and everyone in the JS community knows it. There *should* be this functionality:

```js
const obj1 = {a:4, b:7};
const obj2 = Object.map(obj1, (k,v) => v + 5);
    
console.log(obj1); // {a:4, b:7}
console.log(obj2); // {a:9, b:12}
```

here is the naïve implementation:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object, 'map', {
    value: function(obj, fn, ctx) {
        const ret = {};

        for(let k of Object.keys(obj)){
            ret[k] = fn.call(ctx || null, k, obj[k]);
        });

        return ret;
    },
    enumerable: false
};
```

it is super annoying to have to implement this yourself all the time ;)

If you want something a little more sophisticated, that doesn't interfere with the Object class, try this:

```js
const map = function (obj, fn, ctx) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = fn.call(ctx || null, b, obj[b]);
    return a;
  }, {});
};


const x = map({a: 2, b: 4}, (k,v) => {
    return v*2;
});
```

It is safe to add this map function to `Object`; be careful not to assign directly to `Object.prototype` - if you want to extend a prototype use `Object.defineProperty` with `enumerable: false`

```
// fairly safe:
Object.map = ...

// not ok (causes all objects to have a "map" property):
Object.prototype.map ...

// fairly safe:
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, map, { value: ..., enumerable: false });
```

Comment: Why do you add this function to the global `Object` object? Just have `const mapObject = (obj, fn) => { [...]; return ret; }`.

Comment: Because it should be a method on Object :)

Comment: As long as we don't mess with Object.prototype then we should be ok

Comment: If map were just a random vague thing, sure.  But `.map` is generally understood as a Functor interface, and there's no single definition of Functor for "Object" because virtually anything in javascript can be an Object, including things with their own very distinct and defined .map interfaces/logic.

Comment: here a mess with arguments passed to map callback

Comment: You could do a check to see if Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype and if that's false, through an error.

Comment: are you thinking (v, k) instead of (k,v)? Yes, I can understand your PoV, to me it doesn't matter, as long as it's consistent with other similar APIs.

Comment: In my opinion first argument of callback should be iterated element itself, not a key. For example i assume it should give me same object, as it usualy happen with common map : Object.map({prop:1}, el => el) but it returns keys with value of same key name...

Comment: you may prefer the Array.prototype.reduce technique instead of the original one.

Comment: also, note that fn.call(null) is opinionated, I think that it needs to be another context besides null.

Comment: Why do we need use .call at all? To avoid wrong context?

Comment: You need Function.prototype.call or Function.prototype.apply so that you can use the appropriate context, as need be. in this case, it's hardcoded to null, but you may wish to use a different value. In other similar official APIs, the context is an optional 3rd argument to the outer function.

Comment: What's inherently wrong about adding the function to Object.prototype? It could be added as non-enumerable function. Or are you worried about objects that might have `map` as a key, obscuring the `map()` function?

Comment: Ever heard of the law of unintended consequences Simon?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I'd love to hear what unintended consequences you could imagine resulting from adding non-enumerable properties to a native prototype, if you would care to share!

Answer (score 27):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then `forEach` over the returned array of keys:

```
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
    newObject = {};
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function (key) {
    var value = myObject[key];
    newObject[key] = value * value;
});
```

Or in a more modular fashion:

```
function map(obj, callback) {
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        result[key] = callback.call(obj, obj[key], key, obj);
    });
    return result;
}

newObject = map(myObject, function(x) { return x * x; });
```

Note that `Object.keys` returns an array containing only the object's own enumerable properties, thus it behaves like a `for..in` loop with a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Answer (score 23):

## Minimal version

### ES2017

```js
Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = v * v, a), {})
                                                  ↑↑↑↑↑
```

### ES2019

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, v * v]))
                                                           ↑↑↑↑↑
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect because of a typo, I think you mean =>  `Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => [a[k] = v * v, a], {})`, angled-brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, my code is correct. Read more about comma operator inside parentheses : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: basically, my code is equivalent to: `Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {a[k] = v * v; return a}, {})`

Comment: Webstorm warns the developer of usage of "comma expressions" saying that they "are normally the sign of overly clever code" ... lol just sayin'

Comment: And he's right. for a more understandable code, use loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722/806169

Answer (score 18):

I came here looking to find and answer for mapping an object to an array and got this page as a result. In case you came here looking for the same answer I was, here is how you can map and object to an array.

You can use map to return a new array from the object like so:

```
var newObject = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) {
   return myObject[key];
});
```

Comment: This doesn't remotely work - it just returns an array of the values of the object, not a new object.  I can't believe it has this many up-votes.

Comment: You are correct, it does not answer the question correctly as they were looking for an answer for mapping an object to and object. I came here looking for an answer for mapping an object to an array and got this page as a result, so I will leave my answer and edit it to reflect that it is an alternate answer for people who may have gotten here as a result of looking for mapping an object to arrays.

Comment: In ES7 that'll trivially be `Object.values(myObject)`

Comment: const obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.entries(obj)); // [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 42] ]

Comment: This doesn't work, just outputs an array with the object values

Answer (score 17):

JavaScript just got the new `Object.fromEntries` method.

### Example

```js
function mapObject (obj, fn) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(obj)
      .map(fn)
  )
}

const myObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
const myNewObject = mapObject(myObject, ([key, value]) => ([key, value * value]))
console.log(myNewObject)
```

### Explanation

The code above converts the Object into an nested Array (`[[<key>,<value>], ...]`) wich you can map over. `Object.fromEntries` converts the Array back to an Object.

The cool thing about this pattern, is that you can now easily take object keys into account while mapping.

### Documentation

- [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

### Browser Support

`Object.fromEntries` is currently only supported by [these browsers/engines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility), nevertheless there are polyfills available (e.g [@babel/polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill)).

Comment: Basically, `Object.fromEntries` is the opposite of `Object.entries`.
`Object.entries` converts an object to a list of key-value pairs.
`Object.fromEntries` converts a list of key-value pairs to an object.

Comment: Not a bad solution. Clean and simple. Except function params are different to `Array.map()`. My preference would be for the map function params to be `(value, key)`. I know this seems somewhat backwards, however that's the order used for `Array.map()` and `Array.forEach()` so it's more consistent.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer has two drawbacks:

- It misuses `Array.prototype.reduce`, because reducing means to change the structure of a composite type, which doesn't happen in this case.
- It is not particularly reusable

---

#### An ES6/ES2015 functional approach

Please note that all functions are defined in curried form.

```js
// small, reusable auxiliary functions

const keys = o => Object.keys(o);

const assign = (...o) => Object.assign({}, ...o);

const map = f => xs => xs.map(x => f(x));

const mul = y => x => x * y;

const sqr = x => mul(x) (x);


// the actual map function

const omap = f => o => {
  o = assign(o); // A
  map(x => o[x] = f(o[x])) (keys(o)); // B
  return o;
};


// mock data

const o = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};


// and run

console.log(omap(sqr) (o));
console.log(omap(mul(10)) (o));
```

- In line A `o` is reassigned. Since Javascript passes reference values [by sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38533677/6445533), a shallow copy of `o` is generated. We are now able to mutate `o` within `omap` without mutating `o` in the parent scope.
- In line B `map`'s return value is ignored, because `map` performs a mutation of `o`. Since this side effect remains within `omap` and isn't visible in the parent scope, it is totally acceptable.

This is not the fastest solution, but a declarative and reusable one. Here is the same implementation as a one-line, succinct but less readable:

```
const omap = f => o => (o = assign(o), map(x => o[x] = f(o[x])) (keys(o)), o);
```

---

#### Addendum - why are objects not iterable by default?

ES2015 specified the iterator and iterable protocols. But objects are still not iterable and thus not mappable. [The reason is the mixing of data and program level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38777177/6445533).

Comment: Looks like a bit over engineered; I count 6 functions for what's essentially a loop. Other solutions are far simpler and the accepted answer is 5 times faster too.

Comment: @bfred.it What is the purpose of your comment? If you like micro-optimization you shouldn't use `Array.prototype.reduce` either. All I want to illustrate here is that the accepted answer somehow "abuses" `Array.prototype.reduce` and how a purely functional mapping could be implemented. If you're not interested in functional programming, just ignore my answer.

Comment: If you're not interested in performance and simplicity, don't read my comment then. :) A lot of features are "abused" but sometimes they fit the abuse better than other solutions.

Comment: @naomik: I like `Reflect.ownKeys` too, because it is so honest. But this question is about iterating over the data level of an `Object`. Since `Reflect.ownKeys` iterates over all own properties not just the enumerable ones, I replaced it with `Object.keys`.

Comment: "reducing means to change the structure of a composite type" I don't think that's true. An Array.reduce that produces a new array of the exact same length or even the exact same values is perfectly legitimate.  Reduce can be use to re-create the functionality of map and/or filter (or both, as in a complex transducer, for which reduce is the basis). In FP, it's a type of fold, and a fold that ends up with the same type is still a fold.

Comment: @Dtipson You're absolutely right. A `fold` is more generic than a `map` (functor). However, this was my knowledge from mid-2016. That's half an eternity :D

Comment: @Dtipson The real problem is that the OP wants to fold an `Object`, which he shouldn't and that an `Object` is a mix of a dictionary and a record in Javascript.

Comment: Note that map does not mutate the array but returns a new one. `const omap = f => o => map(x => o[x] = f(o[x])) (keys(o))`

Answer (score 10):

For maximum performance.

If your object doesn't change often but needs to be iterated on often I suggest using a native Map as a cache.

```js
// example object
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 'something'};

// caching map
var objMap = new Map(Object.entries(obj));

// fast iteration on Map object
objMap.forEach((item, key) => {
  // do something with an item
  console.log(key, item);
});
```

Object.entries already works in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and beta Opera so it's a future-proof feature.
It's from ES7 so polyfill it https://github.com/es-shims/Object.entries for IE where it doesn't work.

Comment: How about using **Destructing**?

Comment: @K._ it used to be very slow, but I don't know about performance now. It looks like V8 v 5.6 introduced some optimisations for destructuring but that must be measured http://v8project.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Or, less performant es7 but immutable: `const fn = v => v * 2; const newObj = Object.entries(myObject).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => Object.assign({}, acc, {[k]: fn(v)}), {});`

Answer (score 9):

You can convert an object to array simply by using the following:

**You can convert the object values to an array:**

```js
myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

let valuesArray = Object.values(myObject);

console.log(valuesArray);
```

**You can convert the object keys to an array:**

```js
myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

let keysArray = Object.keys(myObject);

console.log(keysArray);
```

**Now you can perform normal array operations, including the 'map' function**

Comment: In 2020, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

you can use `map` method and `forEach` on arrays but if you want to use it on `Object` then you can use it with twist like below:

**Using Javascript (ES6)**

```
var obj = { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 };   
Object.entries(obj).map( v => obj[v[0]] *= v[1] );
console.log(obj); //it will log as {a: 4, b: 16, c: 36}

var obj2 = { 'a': 4, 'b': 8, 'c': 10 };
Object.entries(obj2).forEach( v => obj2[v[0]] *= v[1] );
console.log(obj2); //it will log as {a: 16, b: 64, c: 100}
```

**Using jQuery**

```
var ob = { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 };
$.map(ob, function (val, key) {
   ob[key] *= val;
});
console.log(ob) //it will log as {a: 4, b: 16, c: 36}
```

Or you can use other loops also like `$.each` method as below example:

```
$.each(ob,function (key, value) {
  ob[key] *= value;
});
console.log(ob) //it will also log as {a: 4, b: 16, c: 36}
```

Comment: Where `$` is jquery?

Comment: Yes you can use both $ and jQuery

Comment: @Ronald i have misunderstood, see my updated answer, thanks for not downvoting but truly making aware to my mistake, thanks for improving community.

Comment: @bcoughlan yes it is exactly which i have written in comment too, it is squaring the numbers, what do you want then?

Comment: @abalter , ronald has written that when i have not mentioned that i was using jQuery for solving it, but if you can see it now it is mentioned clearly on code blocks, so what is the problem dude?

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil I took it to mean that he was criticizing you for giving a jQuery solution. It's true that there is some impetus these days to move away from jQuery, and of course there is Node, but unless an OP asks specifically for pure JS or Node, I think it's fine to assume someone is working in a web environment and that jQuery is almost certain to be available.

Answer (score 6):

The `map function` does not exist on the `Object.prototype` however you can emulate it like so

```
var myMap = function ( obj, callback ) {

    var result = {};

    for ( var key in obj ) {
        if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, key ) ) {
            if ( typeof callback === 'function' ) {
                result[ key ] = callback.call( obj, obj[ key ], key, obj );
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

};

var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

var newObject = myMap( myObject, function ( value, key ) {
    return value * value;
});
```

Comment: Perfomance issues: `typeof callback === 'function'` absolutely redundant. 1) `map` has no meaning without callback 2) if `callback` isn't function, yours `map` implementation just runs meaningless for-loop. Also, `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, key )` is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: The canonical way using newer JavaScript features is -

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const omap = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([ k, v ]) =>
      [ k, f(v) ]
    )
  )
```

Where `o` is some object and `f` is your mapping function. Or we could say, given a function from `a -> b`, and an object with values of type `a`, produce an object with values of type `b`. As a pseudo type signature -

```
// omap : (a -> b, { a }) -> { b }
```

---

The original answer was written to demonstrate a powerful combinator, `mapReduce` which allows us to think of our transformation in a different way

1. `m`, the *mapping* function – gives you a chance to transform the incoming element before…
2. `r`, the *reducing* function – this function combines the accumulator with the result of the mapped element

Intuitively, `mapReduce` creates a new reducer we can plug directly into `Array.prototype.reduce`. But more importantly, we can implement our object functor implementation `omap` plainly by utilizing the object monoid, `Object.assign` and `{}`.

```js
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const mapReduce = (m, r) =>
  (a, x) => r (a, m (x))

const omap = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  Object
    .keys (o)
    .reduce
      ( mapReduce
          ( k => ({ [k]: f (o[k]) })
          , Object.assign
          )
      , {}
      )
          
const square = x =>
  x * x
  
const data =
  { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3 }
  
console .log (omap (square, data))
// { a : 1, b : 4, c : 9 }
```

Notice the only part of the program we actually had to write is the mapping implementation itself –

```
k => ({ [k]: f (o[k]) })
```

Which says, given a known object `o` and some key `k`, construct an object and whose computed property `k` is the result of calling `f` on the key's value, `o[k]`.

We get a glimpse of `mapReduce`'s sequencing potential if we first abstract `oreduce`

```
// oreduce : (string * a -> string * b, b, { a }) -> { b }
const oreduce = (f = identity, r = null, o = {}) =>
  Object
    .keys (o)
    .reduce
      ( mapReduce
          ( k => [ k, o[k] ]
          , f
          )
      , r
      )

// omap : (a -> b, {a}) -> {b}
const omap = (f = identity, o = {}) =>
  oreduce
    ( mapReduce
        ( ([ k, v ]) =>
            ({ [k]: f (v) })
        , Object.assign
        )
    , {}
    , o
    )
```

Everything works the same, but `omap` can be defined at a higher-level now. Of course the new `Object.entries` makes this look silly, but the exercise is still important to the learner.

You won't see the full potential of `mapReduce` here, but I share this answer because it's interesting to see just how many places it can be applied. If you're interested in how it is derived and other ways it could be useful, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505969/633183).

Comment: Let us rather use `Map` and `Map.entries`, OK :D. I'm tired of abusing plain objects as map data types.

Comment: I agree `Map` should be used where/when possible, but it does not totally replace the need to use these procedures on plain JS objects tho :D

Answer (score 6):

```
  const array = Object.keys(object)
  //returns all keys as array ["key", "key"]

  const array = Object.values(object)
  //returns all values as array ["value", "value"]

  const array = Object.entries(object)
  //returns all entries as array = [["key","value"], ["key","value"]]
```

Use Map on the result.

```
  array.map()
```

Answer (score 4):

### Object Mapper in TypeScript

I like the examples that use `Object.fromEntries` such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110762/450913), but still, they are not very easy to use. The answers that use `Object.keys` and then look up the `key` are actually doing multiple look-ups that may not be necessary.

I wished there was an `Object.map` function, but we can create our own and call it `objectMap` with the ability to modify both `key` and `value`:

**Usage (JavaScript):**

```
const myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

// keep the key and modify the value
let obj = objectMap(myObject, val => val * 2);
// obj = { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6 }


// modify both key and value
obj = objectMap(myObject,
    val => val * 2 + '',
    key => (key + key).toUpperCase());
// obj = { AA: '2', BB: '4', CC: '6' }
```

**Code (TypeScript):**

```js
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

function objectMap<TValue, TResult>(
    obj: Dictionary<TValue>,
    valSelector: (val: TValue, obj: Dictionary<TValue>) => TResult,
    keySelector?: (key: string, obj: Dictionary<TValue>) => string,
    ctx?: Dictionary<TValue>
) {
    const ret = {} as Dictionary<TResult>;
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        const retKey = keySelector
            ? keySelector.call(ctx || null, key, obj)
            : key;
        const retVal = valSelector.call(ctx || null, obj[key], obj);
        ret[retKey] = retVal;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you are not using TypeScript then copy the above code in [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to get the JavaScript code.

Also, the reason I put `keySelector` after `valSelector` in the parameter list, is because it is optional.

* Some credit go to alexander-mills' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008272/450913).

Comment: This doesn't work with optional properties on obj. For that, you to pick those out separately and union them together when creating the dictionary. Something like: type Dictionary<T extends object, TValue> = {
  [key in RequiredKeys<T>]: TValue;
} & {
  [key in OptionalKeys<T>]?: TValue;
};

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Amberlamps answer, here's a utility function
(as a comment it looked ugly)

```
function mapObject(obj, mapFunc){
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(newObj, value) {
        newObj[value] = mapFunc(obj[value]);
        return newObj;
    }, {});
}
```

and the use is:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:3, c:5}
function double(x){return x * 2}

var newObj = mapObject(obj, double);
//=>  {a: 2, b: 6, c: 10}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came upon this as a first-item in a Google search trying to learn to do this, and thought I would share for other folsk finding this recently the solution I found, which uses the npm package immutable.

I think its interesting to share because immutable uses the OP's EXACT situation in their own documentation - the following is not my own code but pulled from the current immutable-js documentation:

```
const { Seq } = require('immutable')
const myObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
Seq(myObject).map(x => x * x).toObject();
// { a: 1, b: 4, c: 9 }
```

Not that Seq has other properties ("Seq describes a lazy operation, allowing them to efficiently chain use of all the higher-order collection methods (such as map and filter) by not creating intermediate collections") and that some other immutable-js data structures might also do the job quite efficiently.

Anyone using this method will of course have to `npm install immutable` and might want to read the docs:

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Answer (score 3):

This is my way to do it and results to be worth in terms of efficiency and readability.

```js
myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

const newObject = Object.entries(myObject)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value * value}`)
  .join(', ');

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

My response is largely based off the highest rated response here and hopefully everyone understands (have the same explanation on my GitHub, too). This is why his impementation with map works:

```
Object.keys(images).map((key) => images[key] = 'url(' + '"' + images[key] + '"' +    
')');
```

The purpose of the function is to take an object and modify the original contents of the object using a method available to all objects (objects and arrays alike) without returning an array. Almost everything within JS is an object, and for that reason elements further down the pipeline of inheritance can potentially technically use those available to those up the line (and the reverse it appears).

The reason that this works is due to the .map functions returning an array REQUIRING that you provide an explicit or implicit RETURN of an array instead of simply modifying an existing object. You essentially trick the program into thinking the object is an array by using Object.keys which will allow you to use the map function with its acting on the values the individual keys are associated with (I actually accidentally returned arrays but fixed it). As long as there isn't a return in the normal sense, there will be no array created with the original object stil intact and modified as programmed.

This particular program takes an object called images and takes the values of its keys and appends url tags for use within another function. Original is this:

```
var images = { 
snow: 'https://www.trbimg.com/img-5aa059f5/turbine/bs-md-weather-20180305', 
sunny: 'http://www.cubaweather.org/images/weather-photos/large/Sunny-morning-east-   
Matanzas-city- Cuba-20170131-1080.jpg', 
rain: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/23/d8
/ab/23d8ab1eebc72a123cebc80ce32b43d8.jpg' };
```

...and modified is this:

```
var images = { 
snow: url('https://www.trbimg.com/img-5aa059f5/turbine/bs-md-weather-20180305'),     
sunny: url('http://www.cubaweather.org/images/weather-photos/large/Sunny-morning-   
east-Matanzas-city- Cuba-20170131-1080.jpg'), 
rain: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/23/d8
/ab/23d8ab1eebc72a123cebc80ce32b43d8.jpg') 
};
```

The object's original structure is left intact allowing for normal property access as long as there isn't a return. Do NOT have it return an array like normal and everything will be fine. The goal is REASSIGNING the original values (images[key]) to what is wanted and not anything else. As far as I know, in order to prevent array output there HAS to be REASSIGNMENT of images[key] and no implicit or explicit request to return an array (variable assignment does this and was glitching back and forth for me).

EDIT:

Going to address his other method regarding new object creation to avoid modifying original object (and reassignment appears to still be necessary in order to avoid accidentally creating an array as output). These functions use arrow syntax and are if you simply want to create a new object for future use.

```
const mapper = (obj, mapFn) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => {
                result[key] = mapFn(obj)[key];
                return result;
            }, {});

var newImages = mapper(images, (value) => value);
```

The way these functions work is like so:

mapFn takes the function to be added later (in this case (value) => value) and simply returns whatever is stored there as a value for that key (or multiplied by two if you change the return value like he did) in mapFn(obj)[key],

and then redefines the original value associated with the key in result[key] = mapFn(obj)[key]

and returns the operation performed on result (the accumulator located in the brackets initiated at the end of the .reduce function).

All of this is being performed on the chosen object and STILL there CANNOT be an implicit request for a returned array and only works when reassigning values as far as I can tell. This requires some mental gymnastics but reduces the lines of code needed as can be seen above. Output is exactly the same as can be seen below:

```
{snow: "https://www.trbimg.com/img-5aa059f5/turbine/bs-   
md-weather-20180305", sunny: "http://www.cubaweather.org/images/weather-
photos/l…morning-east-Matanzas-city-Cuba-20170131-1080.jpg", rain: 
"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/23/d8
/ab/23d8ab1eebc72a123cebc80ce32b43d8.jpg"}
```

Keep in mind this worked with NON-NUMBERS. You CAN duplicate ANY object by SIMPLY RETURNING THE VALUE in the mapFN function.

Answer (score 2):

```
const mapObject = (targetObject, callbackFn) => {
    if (!targetObject) return targetObject;
    if (Array.isArray(targetObject)){
        return targetObject.map((v)=>mapObject(v, callbackFn))
    }
    return Object.entries(targetObject).reduce((acc,[key, value]) => {
        const res = callbackFn(key, value);
        if (!Array.isArray(res) && typeof res ==='object'){
            return {...acc, [key]: mapObject(res, callbackFn)}
        }
        if (Array.isArray(res)){
            return {...acc, [key]: res.map((v)=>mapObject(v, callbackFn))}
        }
        return {...acc, [key]: res};
    },{})
};
const mapped = mapObject(a,(key,value)=> {
    if (!Array.isArray(value) && key === 'a') return ;
    if (!Array.isArray(value) && key === 'e') return [];
    if (!Array.isArray(value) && key === 'g') return value * value;
    return value;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped)); 
// {"b":2,"c":[{"d":2,"e":[],"f":[{"g":4}]}]}
```

This function goes recursively through the object and arrays of objects. Attributes can be deleted if returned undefined

Answer (score 1):

I needed a version that allowed modifying the keys as well (based on @Amberlamps and @yonatanmn answers);

```
var facts = [ // can be an object or array - see jsfiddle below
    {uuid:"asdfasdf",color:"red"},
    {uuid:"sdfgsdfg",color:"green"},
    {uuid:"dfghdfgh",color:"blue"}
];

var factObject = mapObject({}, facts, function(key, item) {
    return [item.uuid, {test:item.color, oldKey:key}];
});

function mapObject(empty, obj, mapFunc){
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(newObj, key) {
        var kvPair = mapFunc(key, obj[key]);
        newObj[kvPair[0]] = kvPair[1];
        return newObj;
    }, empty);
}
```

factObject=

```
{
"asdfasdf": {"color":"red","oldKey":"0"},
"sdfgsdfg": {"color":"green","oldKey":"1"},
"dfghdfgh": {"color":"blue","oldKey":"2"}
}
```

Edit: slight change to pass in the starting object {}.  Allows it to be [] (if the keys are integers)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };


Object.prototype.map = function(fn){
    var oReturn = {};
    for (sCurObjectPropertyName in this) {
        oReturn[sCurObjectPropertyName] = fn(this[sCurObjectPropertyName], sCurObjectPropertyName);
    }
    return oReturn;
}
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'map',{enumerable:false});





newObject = myObject.map(function (value, label) {
    return value * value;
});


// newObject is now { 'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 9 }
```

Comment: `enumerable` defaults to `false`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone was looking for a simple solution that maps an object to a new object or to an array:

```
// Maps an object to a new object by applying a function to each key+value pair.
// Takes the object to map and a function from (key, value) to mapped value.
const mapObject = (obj, fn) => {
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => { newObj[k] = fn(k, obj[k]); });
    return newObj;
};

// Maps an object to a new array by applying a function to each key+value pair.
// Takes the object to map and a function from (key, value) to mapped value.
const mapObjectToArray = (obj, fn) => (
    Object.keys(obj).map(k => fn(k, obj[k]))
);
```

This may not work for all objects or all mapping functions, but it works for plain shallow objects and straightforward mapping functions which is all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

To responds more closely to what *precisely* the OP asked for, the OP wants an object:

> `myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }`

to have a map method `myObject.map`,

> similar to Array.prototype.map that would be used as follows:
>
> ```
> newObject = myObject.map(function (value, label) {
>     return value * value;
> });
> // newObject is now { 'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 9 }
> ```

The *imho* best (measured in terms to "*close to what is asked*" + "no ES{5,6,7} required needlessly") answer would be:

```
myObject.map = function mapForObject(callback)
{
  var result = {};
  for(var property in this){
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(property) && property != "map"){
      result[property] = callback(this[property],property,this);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The code above avoids intentionally using any language features, only available in recent ECMAScript editions. With the code above the problem can be solved lke this:

```js
myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

myObject.map = function mapForObject(callback)
{
  var result = {};
  for(var property in this){
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(property) && property != "map"){
      result[property] = callback(this[property],property,this);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

newObject = myObject.map(function (value, label) {
  return value * value;
});
console.log("newObject is now",newObject);
```

[alternative test code here](https://alexmahr.de/runjavascript.html#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)

Besides frowned upon by some, it would be a possibility to insert the solution in the prototype chain like this.

```
Object.prototype.map = function(callback)
{
  var result = {};
  for(var property in this){
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(property)){
      result[property] = callback(this[property],property,this);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Something, which when done with careful oversight should not have any ill effects and not impact `map` method of other objects (i.e. Array's `map`).

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your HTMLCollection using Object.entries(collection). Then it’s an iterable you can now use the .map method on it.

```
Object.entries(collection).map(...)
```

reference 
https://medium.com/@js_tut/calling-javascript-code-on-multiple-div-elements-without-the-id-attribute-97ff6a50f31

Answer (score 1):

I handle only strings to reduce exemptions:

```
Object.keys(params).map(k => typeof params[k] == "string" ? params[k] = params[k].trim() : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in `map`ping not only values but also keys, I have written [`Object.map(valueMapper, keyMapper)`](https://github.com/MattiSG/Object.map.js/blob/master/README.md), that behaves this way:

```
var source = { a: 1, b: 2 };
function sum(x) { return x + x }

source.map(sum);            // returns { a: 2, b: 4 }
source.map(undefined, sum); // returns { aa: 1, bb: 2 }
source.map(sum, sum);       // returns { aa: 2, bb: 4 }
```

Comment: If ever useful for anyone: `npm install @mattisg/object.map`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey wrote a little mapper function that might help.

```
    function propertyMapper(object, src){
         for (var property in object) {   
           for (var sourceProp in src) {
               if(property === sourceProp){
                 if(Object.prototype.toString.call( property ) === '[object Array]'){
                   propertyMapper(object[property], src[sourceProp]);
                   }else{
                   object[property] = src[sourceProp];
                }
              }
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

A different take on it is to use a custom json stringify function that can also work on deep objects. This might be useful if you intend to post it to the server anyway as json

```js
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, x: {'c': 3 }}
const json = JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => typeof v === 'number' ? v * v : v)

console.log(json)
console.log('back to json:', JSON.parse(json))
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a function to optionally map not only (nor exclusively) values, but also keys. The original object should not change. The object contained only primitive values also.

```
function mappedObject(obj, keyMapper, valueMapper) {

    const mapped = {};
    const keys   = Object.keys(obj);
    const mapKey = typeof keyMapper == 'function';
    const mapVal = typeof valueMapper == 'function';

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const key = mapKey ? keyMapper(keys[i]) : keys[i];
        const val = mapVal ? valueMapper(obj[keys[i]]) : obj[keys[i]];
        mapped[key] = val;
    }

    return mapped;
}
```

Use. Pass a keymapper and a valuemapper function:

```
const o1 = { x: 1, c: 2 }
mappedObject(o1, k => k + '0', v => v + 1) // {x0: 2, c0: 3}
```

Answer (score -1):

I specifically wanted to use the same function that I was using for arrays for a single object, and wanted to keep it simple. This worked for me:

```
var mapped = [item].map(myMapFunction).pop();
```

Comment: this is no different than `var mapped = myMapFunction(item)`

Answer (score -1):

```js
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
Object.keys(myObject).filter((item) => myObject[item] *= 2)
console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myObject[key] *= 2;
  }
}

console.log(myObject);
// { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }
```

Comment: You might want to always explain your solution. It makes it more useful

Answer (score -1):

Here is another version that allows the mapping function to declare any number of new properties (keys and values) based on the current key and value. E: Now works with arrays too.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'mapEntries', {
  value: function(f,a=Array.isArray(this)?[]:{}) {
    return Object.entries(this).reduce( (o, [k,v]) => 
      Object.assign(o, f(v, Array.isArray(a)?Number(k):k, this)),
      a);
  }
});

const data = { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3 };
const calculate = (v, k) => ({
  [k+'_square']: v*v,
  [k+'_cube']: v*v*v
});
console.log( data.mapEntries( calculate ) );
// {
//  "a_square": 1,  "a_cube": 1,
//  "b_square": 4,  "b_cube": 8,
//  "c_square": 9,  "c_cube": 27
// }

// Demonstration with an array:
const arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
const duplicate = (v, i) => ({
  [i*2]: v,
  [i*2+1]: v+v
});
console.log( arr.mapEntries( duplicate ) );
// [ "a", "aa", "b", "bb", "c", "cc" ]
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const orig = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

const result = _.transform(orig, (r, v, k) => r[k.trim()] = v * 2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Use new  [_.transform() to transforms object](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#transform).

Answer (score -2):

```
settings = {
  message_notification: {
    value: true,
    is_active: true,
    slug: 'message_notification',
    title: 'Message Notification'
  },
  support_notification: {
    value: true,
    is_active: true,
    slug: 'support_notification',
    title: 'Support Notification'
  },
};

let keys = Object.keys(settings);
keys.map(key=> settings[key].value = false )
console.log(settings)
```

Answer (score -2):

ES6:

```
Object.prototype.map = function(mapFunc) {
    return Object.keys(this).map((key, index) => mapFunc(key, this[key], index));
}
```

ES2015:

```
Object.prototype.map = function (mapFunc) {
    var _this = this;

    return Object.keys(this).map(function (key, index) {
        return mapFunc(key, _this[key], index);
    });
};
```

test in node:

```
> a = {foo: "bar"}
{ foo: 'bar' }
> a.map((k,v,i) => v)
[ 'bar' ]
```

Answer (score -2):

## Async, anyone?

Despite of the large number of comments, I didn't find a solution for using an `async` mapper. Here's mine.

Uses [p-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-map), a trusted (@sindresorhus) and small dependency.

(note that no options are passed to `p-map`. Refer to the docs if you need to adjust concurrency/error handling).

### Typescript:

```js
import pMap from "p-map";

export const objectMapAsync = async <InputType, ResultType>(
  object: { [s: string]: InputType } | ArrayLike<InputType>,
  mapper: (input: InputType, key: string, index: number) => Promise<ResultType>
): Promise<{
  [k: string]: ResultType;
}> => {
  const mappedTuples = await pMap(
    Object.entries(object),
    async ([key, value], index) => {
      const result = await mapper(value, key, index);
      return [key, result];
    }
  );

  return Object.fromEntries(mappedTuples);
};
```

### Plain JS:

```js
import pMap from "p-map";

export const objectMapAsync = async (
  object,
  mapper
) => {
  const mappedTuples = await pMap(
    Object.entries(object),
    async ([key, value], index) => {
      const result = await mapper(value, key, index);
      return [key, result];
    }
  );

  return Object.fromEntries(mappedTuples);
};

};
```

### Usage example:

(highly contrived, no error handling, no types)

```js
// Our object in question.
const ourFavouriteCharacters = {
  me: "luke",
  you: "vader",
  everyone: "chewbacca",
};

// An async function operating on the object's values (in this case, strings)
const fetchCharacter = (charName) =>
  fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people?search=${charName}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => res.results[0]);

// `objectMapAsync` will return the final mapped object to us
//  (wrapped in a Promise)
objectMapAsync(ourFavouriteCharacters, fetchCharacter).then((res) =>
  console.log(res)
);
```

Comment: I can't speak for your downvoter; but I'd posit that perhaps 'async map-over-object' is a unique-enough problem-space that it deserves its own question/answer, not an *additional* answer that doesn't help the original asker on a well-and-thoroughly-already-answered Question. (So, less "this is bad and your are bad", and more "that's now how we do things on Stack Exchange." )

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE thank you for taking the time to answer on my comment. I usually only answer questions that I have myself, but where I'm not happy with the given answers. This was such a case. After all, answers should help people landing on a question, not only the poster.

I'll take the liberty of leaving the answer as-is for now. ✌

Comment: Show an example how to use objectMapAsync for newbies?

Comment: @Mecanik added an example, hope it helps

Answer (score -3):

Use following map function to define `myObject.map`

```
o => f=> Object.keys(o).reduce((a,c)=> c=='map' ? a : (a[c]=f(o[c],c),a), {})
```

```js
let map = o => f=> Object.keys(o).reduce((a,c)=> c=='map' ? a : (a[c]=f(o[c],c),a), {})



// TEST init

myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
myObject.map = map(myObject);        

// you can do this instead above line but it is not recommended 
// ( you will see `map` key any/all objects)
// Object.prototype.map = map(myObject);

// OP desired interface described in question
newObject = myObject.map(function (value, label) {
    return  value * value;
});

console.log(newObject);
```