# Mongoose, update values in array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to update values in an object?

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  items: [{
     id: 1,
     name: 'item 1',
     value: 'one'
  },{
     id: 2,
     name: 'item 2',
     value: 'two'
  }]
}
```

Lets say I want to update the name and value items for item where id = 2;

I have tried the following w/ mongoose:

```
var update = {name: 'updated item2', value: 'two updated'};
Person.update({'items.id': 2}, {'$set':  {'items.$': update}}, function(err) { ...
```

Problem with this approach is that it updates/sets the entire object, therefore in this case I lose the id field.

Is there a better way in mongoose to set certain values in an array but leave other values alone?

I have also queried for just the Person:

```
Person.find({...}, function(err, person) {
  person.items ..... // I might be able to search through all the items here and find item with id 2 then update the values I want and call person.save().
});
```

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You're close; you should use dot notation in your use of the [`$` update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to do that:

```
Person.update({'items.id': 2}, {'$set': {
    'items.$.name': 'updated item2',
    'items.$.value': 'two updated'
}}, function(err) { ...
```

Comment: Hello, when I do exactly you suggested.
board.update({ _id: board._id,"users.username": req.user.username}, {$set: {"users.$.lastViewed": new Date()}}, function (err) {});
 I got an error:
cannot use the part (users of users.username) to traverse the element ({users: [ { username: "nlm", _id: ObjectId('583c8cc3813daa6c29f69cb0'), status: "invited", role: "reviewer" } ]}).  Is there anything I did differently?

Comment: This works great, thank you.
However, is there any way to create an item if it's not in the array?

Comment: @SergeyMell if I think that might be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577318/6470918

Comment: How do I update the name for id = 2 in all documents in a collection?

Comment: How would this work if you had an array of objects inside an array? Like instead of just `items.$.name`, you had `items.users.$.status`? would that work?

Comment: hey, i tried this doing but after doing this i have to make two patch request from postman, then only it is updating the value. if any one can help please reply!

Comment: This does not work for me. It always update the first element of the array. However, I solved the problem using arrayFilters. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: And 10 years after this question was originally asked, this solution still stands :-)

Answer (score 61):

```
model.update(
    { _id: 1, "items.id": "2" },
    {
        $set: {
            "items.$.name": "yourValue",
            "items.$.value": "yourvalue",
         }
    }
)
```

[MongoDB Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: Instead of `update` it's better to use `updateOne` or `updateMany`

Answer (score 29):

There is a mongoose way for doing it.

```
const itemId = 2;
const query = {
  item._id: itemId 
};
Person.findOne(query).then(doc => {
  item = doc.items.id(itemId );
  item["name"] = "new name";
  item["value"] = "new value";
  doc.save();

  //sent respnse to client
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Oh! Dark')
});
```

Comment: This method is handy if you are doing an operation on the parent document as well as the array item.

Comment: When I update the document, also updates `_id` of that document? It's strange.

Comment: had to change item = doc.items.id(itemId )  line to item=doc.items.find((item)=>item.id===itemId) and then it worked for me.

Comment: You can use dot notation to make this even easier to read. ie: change item["name"]= "new name" to item.name = "new name"

Answer (score 14):

There is one thing to remember, when you are searching the object in array on the basis of more than one condition then use **$elemMatch**

```
Person.update(
   {
     _id: 5,
     grades: { $elemMatch: { grade: { $lte: 90 }, mean: { $gt: 80 } } }
   },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } }
)
```

here is the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Answer (score 9):

Below is an example of how to update the value in the array of objects more dynamically.

```
Person.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, 
{ 
  "$set": {[`items.$[outer].${propertyName}`]: value} 
},
{ 
  "arrayFilters": [{ "outer.id": itemId }]
},
function(err, response) {
  ...
})
```

Note that by doing it that way, you would be able to update even deeper levels of the nested array by adding additional `arrayFilters` and positional operator like so:

```
"$set": {[`items.$[outer].innerItems.$[inner].${propertyName}`]: value} 

"arrayFilters":[{ "outer.id": itemId },{ "inner.id": innerItemId }]
```

---

More usage can be found in the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Comment: Cool, maybe please add a link to the official docs about this thing

Comment: bro, `"arrayFilters":[{$and:[{ "outer.id": itemId },{ "outer.name": itemName }]}]` . It's not working with mongoose 5.2 and findOneAndUpdate. getting "No array filter found for identifier item ...' . please provide some insights

Comment: @FirojSiddiki I believe your issue is with an outdated  MongoDB Node.JS driver. Please update it to 3.0+. Also, I do not think you need `$and` in there.

Answer (score 7):

For each document, the update operator `$set` can [set multiple values](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), so rather than replacing the entire object in the `items` array, you can set the `name` and `value` fields of the object individually.

```
{'$set':  {'items.$.name': update.name , 'items.$.value': update.value}}
```

Answer (score 6):

cleaner solution using `findOneAndUpdate`

```
  await Person.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id, 'items.id': 2 },
    {
      $set: {
        'items.$.name': 'updated item2', 
        'items.$.value': 'two updated',
      }
    },
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, we can update array value using `$set` inside dot(`.`) notation to specific value in following way

```
db.collection.update({"_id": args._id, "viewData._id": widgetId}, {$set: {"viewData.$.widgetData": widgetDoc.widgetData}})
```

Comment: Would You please edit answer with explanations, or relate to the question?

Comment: Could you possibly take a look at my question, mongoose is removing the part of my query which uses $[] even though it works in the CLI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223672/why-is-mongoose-removing-part-of-my-query

Answer (score 0):

Having tried other solutions which worked fine, but the pitfall of their answers is that only fields already existing would update adding upsert to it would do nothing, so I came up with this.

```
 Person.update({'items.id': 2}, {$set: {
    'items': { "item1",  "item2",  "item3",  "item4" } }, {upsert: 
true })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. Here is the cleanest way to do it.

```
    const personQuery = {
       _id: 1  
    }

    const itemID = 2;

    Person.findOne(personQuery).then(item => {
       const audioIndex = item.items.map(item => item.id).indexOf(itemID);
       item.items[audioIndex].name = 'Name value';
       item.save();
    });
```

Comment: I think In-memory manipulation could lead to processing of outdated data duing very high-write periods.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution using dot-object and it helped me.

```js
import dot from "dot-object";

const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...dot.dot(req.body) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update an array element with dynamic key-value pairs.
By [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722) the update object to new keys containing the `$` update operator, I am no longer bound to know the updated keys of the array element and instead assemble a new update object on the fly.

```js
update = {
  name: "Andy",
  newKey: "new value"
}
new_update = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(update).map(
    ([k, v], i) => ["my_array.$." + k, v]
  )
)
console.log({
  "$set": new_update
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
person.updateMany(
  { "items.id": id },
  {
    $set: {
      "items.$.name": name,
      "items.$.value": value,
    },
  },
  { new: true }
)
   .then((update) => 
  {res.send(update)}).
 catch((err)=>{
res.send(err)})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

In mongoose we can update, like simple array

```
user.updateInfoByIndex(0,"test")

User.methods.updateInfoByIndex = function(index, info) ={
    this.arrayField[index]=info
    this.save()
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful with some explanation. Please consider editing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
update(
    {_id: 1, 'items.id': 2},
    {'$set': {'items.$[]': update}},
    {new: true})
```

Here is the doc about `$[]`: [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up.*S*[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[])

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. it won't replace the whole array

Comment: It is supposed to replace the elements(item having id as 2) of the items array

Comment: I was needing this thanks