# How to add values into JSON-array (node.js/mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose, adding values from HTML and saving to db with help of mongoose. I'm having issue adding value from `req.body.chapter` into array from HTML.

Route:

```
  const newBook = {
      book: req.body.book,
      summary: req.body.summary,
      chapters: //how to add value into chapter-array?
    }
```

Book-model:

```
const BookSchema = new Schema({
 Title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Summary: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  chapters : [{
    chapter: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  }]   
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="book">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="Summary">Summary:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Summary" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="chapter">chapter:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="chapter" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Use array spread? `chapters: [...previousChaptersArray, req.body.chapter]`

Comment: @Li357 I don't quite follow on `...previousChaptersArray`. What am I suppose to write there?

Comment: That is if you want to include previous chapters that you had stored as a variable. Such as you looked up the book, and you are adding chapters. It is better to an "addToSet" if you are just updating, because it stops issues if 2 people are updating it at once.

Comment: @AndrewL Meaning I'll override/delete the previous stored chapters if I don't include, lets say,  `previousChaptersArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the data looks like this, you can just put it in:

```
req.body.chapters = ["1", "3"];
```

Route:

```
const newBook = {
   book: req.body.book,
   summary: req.body.summary,
   chapters: req.body.chapters
 }
```

If you just want to add the chapters to existing data, then have a look at [Using Mongoose / MongoDB $addToSet functionality on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576223/using-mongoose-mongodb-addtoset-functionality-on-array-of-objects)

Comment: Worked, thanks. But how can I can I pass a checkbox value? Checked = true, unchecked = false?