# Mongodb $addToSet array with objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following document

```
{
  "_id": "A",
  "partsIds": [
    {
      "partId": "B",
      "someOtherField": "value"
    },
    {
      "partId": "C",
      "someOtherField": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is `$addToSet` to the `partsIds` array, using the `partId` field value.

So, what I do is

`collection.update({ _id: 'A' }, { $addToSet: { partsIds: { partId: 'B' } } }, {upsert: true});`

This operation adds a new object to `partsIds` array no matter what.

What I am trying to achieve from this is find if `partId === 'B'` exists don't add anything, if it doesn't, it adds it to partsIds array.

How can I achieve this using mongodb?

I found this answer [Using Mongoose / MongoDB $addToSet functionality on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576223/using-mongoose-mongodb-addtoset-functionality-on-array-of-objects)

But it doesn't solve my problem, since it adds a new document when used with `upsert`.

The way I approached this to get the desired behavior is the following, but I am wondering if there is a way to fully do this on mongo side in one go.

```
let doc = collection.findOne({ _id: 'A', 'partsIds.partId': 'B' });
if (!doc) {
  collection.update({ _id: 'A' }, { $push: { partsIds: { partId: 'B' } } }, { upsert: true });
}
```

Comment: Thats the expected behavior. Your addtoset document should match the nested document you are trying to update.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work that way.
I had to do this to get the desired behavior:
`let doc = collection.findOne({_id:"A", 'partsIds.partId':'B'});

if(!doc) {
  collection.update({ _id: 'A' }, { $push: { partsIds: { partId: 'B' } } }, {upsert: true});
}`

Comment: Have you found a way since? I'm tryin to do the same kind of update using mongoose and struggling finding how without 2 calls as you do