# MongoDB/Mongoose - Adding an object to an array of objects only if a certain field is unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

So I have a nested array of objects in my MongoDB document and I would like to add a new object to the array only if a certain field (in this case, eventId) is unique. My question is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576223/using-mongoose-mongodb-addtoset-functionality-on-array-of-objects), only I cannot seem to get that solution to work in my case.

Here is what the documents (`UserModel`) look like:

```
{
  "portal" : {
    "events" : [ 
      {
        "important" : false,
        "completed" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c2a93bb49c91ef8de0b21"),
        "eventId" : "5bec4a7361853025400ee9e9",
        "user_notes" : "My event note"
      },
      ...and so on
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is my (so far unsuccessful) Mongoose operation:

```
UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  userId,
  { "portal.events.eventId": { $ne: req.body.eventId } },
  { $addToSet: { "portal.events": req.body } },
  { new: true }
);
```

Basically I am trying to use `'$ne'` to check if the field is unique, and then `'$addToSet'` (or `'$push'`, I believe they are functionally equivalent in this case) to add the new object.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Gabe

Comment: Why dont you use findOneAndUpdate and have the `$ne: req.body.eventId` inside your query? Also, findByIdAndUpdate only takes 3 parameters (if 4, the last one would be a callback), and you are sending 4 parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) on your method you will see that the parameters passed are not in the proper order.

```
findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options, callback)
```

I would use `update` instead and have your `id` and `portal.events.eventId": { $ne: req.body.eventId }` part of the initial filter followed by `$addToSet: { "portal.events": req.body }`

Something among these lines:

```
UserModel.update(
  { 
     "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), 
     "portal.events.eventId": { $ne: req.body.eventId }
  },
  { $addToSet: { "portal.events": req.body } },
  { new: true }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your `eventId` check into condition part of your query. Because you're usig [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) you can only pass single value matched against `_id` as a condition. Therefore you have to use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to specify custom filtering condition, try:

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userId, "portal.events.eventId": { $ne: req.body.eventId } },
    { $addToSet: { "portal.events": req.body } },
    { new: true }
);
```