# Doubts on Mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was designing a classifieds web app with the MERN stack. The MongoSchema is as shown below

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    books: [{
        title: { type: String },
        author: { type: String },
        desc: { type: String },
        price: { type: String },
        image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
    }],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

So all the other info except the `books[]` will be available after the initial sign-up, but what I want to do is to update the `books` array every time the user wishes to post a book for selling.

I'm planning to find the user by `id`, but I'm not quite sure how to add/append the info to the `books` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some answers to your question already in Stackoverflow.
For example:
[Using Mongoose / MongoDB $addToSet functionality on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576223/using-mongoose-mongodb-addtoset-functionality-on-array-of-objects)

You can do something like this:

**UserModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    books: [{
        title: { type: String },
        author: { type: String },
        desc: { type: String },
        price: { type: String },
        image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
    }],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

After that, in your router file you can try something like this for the books array:

```
const res = await User.updateOne({ email: 'gintama@bandainamco.com' }, {'$addToSet':{
'books':{
        title: "Gintama: The Final",
        author: "Sorachi",
        desc: "Final Arc",
        price: "44.99",
        image: "src"
    }}); //addToSet if you don't want any duplicates in your array.
```

OR

```
const res = await User.updateOne({ email: 'gintama@bandainamco.com' }, {'$push':{
    'books':{
            title: "Gintama: The Final",
            author: "Sorachi",
            desc: "Final Arc",
            price: "44.99",
            image: "src"
        }}); //push if duplicates are okay in your array
```

Comment: Thanks, so ```addToSet``` was what I was missing.

Comment: Yes. In some cases where you might work with quantitative numerical array, you will need push operator.