# mongoose update item in array object

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a data similar to this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aff8a15fac9291cb0477c87"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5adbf5ffd08592252c0efeba"),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2018-05-19T02:21:09.943Z"),
    "category" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "c1bf0790-5b0b-11e8-8c5d-cd2d06b6e60a",
                    "catname" : "art",
                    "introduction" : "The world is waiting for a new way in art",
                    "banner" : null
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "vhjv87t8g-11e885b0b-sjhvikawik",
                    "catname" : "art",
                    "introduction" : "The world is waiting for a new way in art",
                    "banner" : null
            }

    ],
```

When I try to query a single object in array category which looks like this

```
 newCat = user.category.find(element => element.catname.toString() === category.catname.toString() );
    Model.findByIdAndUpdate({'category._id': newCat._id}, {$set: { 
                    "category.$.catname": catalog.catname,
                    "category.$.intro": catalog.introduction,
                    "category.$.lastUpdate": catalog.lastUpdate,  
                    } 
                }, cb);
```

So, to get the category with catname or update the data with catname , I found out  here
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691224/mongoose-update-values-in-array-of-objects) that I have to add _id after adding to it the result are the same it gives me the whole data and I don't want to update the whole data I want to update only the  founded object. later on, I study the dot.notation is used for the array I change my variable to this

```
 newCat = user.category.findIndex(element => element.catname.toString() === category.catname.toString() );
```

also the result are the same I have try many route and waste a day on this. I hope anyone can find a solution to this. Even javasceipt is a lot simpler to update array than mongoose. I am getting tired of using array in mongodb.
Regards, Thanks.

Comment: @Neil Lunn The link you provided is not an array based, it far easy to update data without array than this array-objectnbase. Thanks

Comment: The provided link does not need to be about updating an array since you already have that part of the code correct. What you are doing incorrectly is addressed in the answer there. You need `{ new: true }` in order to return the updated document.