# Why is mongoose removing part of my query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query which works in the mongoDB CLI:

```
db.organisations.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5f687da23a4dc9071baefd6d")}, {$pull: {courseIds: 
ObjectId("5f687b863a4dc9071baefd6c"), "groups.$[].courseIds": 
ObjectId("5f687b863a4dc9071baefd6c") }})
```

And the following query which is what I believe to be the mongoose equivalent:

```
await Organisation.updateOne({_id: "5f687da23a4dc9071baefd6d"},
{$pull: {courseIds: "5f687b863a4dc9071baefd6c", "groups.$[].courseIds": 
"5f687b863a4dc9071baefd6c"}})
```

Using mongoose debugging I can see that the following query which mongoose translates to is removing the entire second half of my pull operation for all documents in the array. Why is this?

```
organisations.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5f687da23a4dc9071baefd6d") }, { '$pull': { 
courseIds: ObjectId("5f687b863a4dc9071baefd6c") } }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have the big stupid. My mongoose schemas were incorrect.