# change only one field of entire array of embedded document in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

i have a list schema and a question set schema. the quetsionSet schema is embedded inside the list schema. its working fine but how can i update anything inside the array of embedded document i.e. here i want to change the *listname* of all the documents inside *questionSet* (array of questionSet documents).

here is an example of my list document model

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc07275bbb30d8cb268e"), 
"listName" : "dsa", 
"aboutList" : "dsa queestions",
 questionSet" : [ { "solved" : false, 
                   "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc12275bbb30d8cb2695"), 
                    "topic" : "array", 
                     "name" : "array is best", 
                    "url" : "www.arr.com", 
                       "listname" : "dsa", 
                     "__v" : 0 }, 
               { "solved" : false,  
                 "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc1b275bbb30d8cb269d"), 
                "topic" : "linked list",
               "name" : "reverse list", 
                 "url" : "www.list.com",
                "listname" : "dsa",
                 "__v" : 0 } 
               ], 
"__v" : 2 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose, update values in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691224/mongoose-update-values-in-array-of-objects)

Comment: bro i tried this but it is still not updating all the documents but its just updating the first document it finds and i tried using update many but no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following in your case

```
db.<collection_name>.updateOne(
    {   "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc07275bbb30d8cb268e")},
    {
      $set: {
        'questionSet.$[].listname': "javascript"
      }
    } 
  )
```

Comment: thank you bro. btw if i want to update the fields provided by form (i am using req.body and storing it in an object and removing all the fields that are left empty) so how can i update the fields which are present in the object should it be like inside $set "questionSet" : myObject or what?

Comment: Yes that shoud work, you should try and test, btw if you find the answer useful, please upvote the answer

Comment: ok thanks bro. i tried it and its working fine but if i just pass 2/3 fields it removes the 3rd field and if i pass 1 field it removes the rest 2 from the database so any fix for it?

Comment: Not clear about question, btw try google there are lot of answer there