# How to add new property to object that I findByID in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an object in mongodb that i want to add new player its property called **players**. [image]

I have have created a router with **findByIdAndUpdate** but couldn't success to add **new player** to my **players** property.This is how I created it. It is not adding new one, but it updates the old property. I looked on mongoose document and looked at StackOverflow, I can't find how to do it.

```js
router.post("/addPlayer/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { players: { name: "mehmet", age: 25 } },
    function (err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Updated User : ", docs);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Here I want to add new player to for example,

```
 {player:'ali',age:22}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Players` is an array if you want to append new players to it you can use `$push` like this:

```
router.post("/addPlayer/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { $push: { players: { name: "mehmet", age: 25 } }},
    function (err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Updated User : ", docs);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

If you want to update the first index you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691224/mongoose-update-values-in-array-of-objects) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since its an array, you can just simply do a `push` and `save`.