# Mongoose: Dynamically update values in nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an API endpoint, where a user can update nested entries of data in a nested array. The user can update one, many or all entries in that nested data, so I can't hardcode the paths. In abstract, it looks something like this.

#### Data format

```json
{
  "id": 4211,
  "foo": "some data",
  "bar": [
    {
      "id": 1
      "a": 123,
      "b": {
        "b1": "abc",
        "b2": "def"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Example updates

The update will be provided as a dotified version of an object.

```js
update1 = {
  'b.b1': "vvv"
}

update2 = {
  'a': 1337,
  'b.b2': "zup"
}
```

#### Update function

```js
async function updateNestedDataBar(baseId, id, update) {
  return await UserData.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: baseId, 'bar.id': id }, // To make sure that the subdoc exists
    { $set: { 'bar.$': update },
    { new: true }
  );
}
```

## Problem

When I update the data with the shown implementation, then it overwrites the whole `bar` object with the provided id. For example, `update1` from above would result in this:

```json
{
  "id": 4211,
  "foo": "some data",
  "bar": [
    {
      "b": {
        "b1": "vvv",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## What I've tried so far

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493932/6608142) to a similar question, I have tried to rewrite the code like this. Still it overrides the whole nested object.

```js
UserData.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: baseId, 'bar.id': id }, // To make sure that the subdoc exists
  { $set: { 'bar.$[outer]': update },
  { 
    arrayFilters: [{ 'outer.id': id }],
    new: true
  }
);
```

I have also tried to do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062391/6608142), by getting the whole document, modifiying it and then `save()` it. But I can't get it to work and I also don't want to fetch the whole document first. Plus I want to keep the benefit of the atomic operation with `findOneAndUpdate`.

Additionally, I have tried something crazy. Doesn't work.

```js
UserData.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: baseId, 'bar.id': id }, // To make sure that the subdoc exists
  `bar.$.${update}`,
  { new: true }
);
```

## Question

1. How can I achieve the desired result?
2. Is there a good documentation on the `UpdateQuery` type in mongoose? I can't find anything in the offical docs that describes my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would slightly modify your function to below:-

```
async function updateNestedDataBar(baseId, id, update) {
  let updateQuery = {};

  // Iterate through the keys in the update object
  Object.keys(update).forEach((key) => {
  // Use dynamic key to update the nested fields
  updateQuery['bar.$.' + key] = update[key];
});

return await UserData.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: baseId, 'bar.id': id }, // To make sure that the subdoc exists
  { $set: updateQuery },
  { new: true }
 );
}
```

This `updateNestedDataBar` function iterates through the keys of the `update` object, constructs the `updateQuery` dynamically, and then uses this query in the `findOneAndUpdate` method to update the specified nested fields within the `bar` array's object.

Now, you can use the `updateNestedDataBar` function with various update objects, such as `update1` and `update2` you provided

```
const update1 = {
  'b.b1': 'vvv'
};

const update2 = {
  'a': 1337,
  'b.b2': 'zup'
};

// Call the function with update1
const updatedData1 = await updateNestedDataBar(baseId, id, update1);

// Call the function with update2
const updatedData2 = await updateNestedDataBar(baseId, id, update2);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I have put it into a separate general purpose function `buildUpdateQuery(update, prefix)`. I simply use it like this: `findOneAndUpdate({...}, buildUpdateQuery(update, 'bar.$.'), {...})`.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Yes, you can always do the refactoring whenever you have time ;-). Kindly accept the answer for other's reference.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to [collab-with-tushar-raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77667421/6608142), here a quick general purpose solution for anyone trying to solve a similar problem.

```js
function buildUpdateQuery(update, prefix) {
  let updateQuery = {};

  // Iterate through the keys in the update object
  Object.keys(update).forEach((key) => {
    updateQuery[prefix + key] = update[key];
  });

  return updateQuery;
}


async function updateNestedDataBar(baseId, id, update) {
  return await UserData.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: baseId, 'bar.id': id },
    buildUpdateQuery(update, 'bar.$.'),
    { new: true }
  );
}
```