# Other ways to loop through a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

this code below works well but the ESLint plugin show the warning:"Using 'ForinStatement' is not allowed" so i want to change it to other ways to prevent the warning message:

```
    let count = 0;
    for (const key in groups) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(groups[key]) === '[object Object]') {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(groups[key], 'users')) {
          count += groups[key].users.length;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why `const key`? Why not `let` or `var`. Also `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(groups[key], 'users')` can be `groups[key].hasOwnProperty( 'users')`

Comment: @Rajesh Because the `key` doesn't change inside of the body of the loop. That's the recommended practice.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I didn't know this. But will second iteration not try to override it as `const key` will be hoisted?

Comment: Would `Object.keys(groups).forEach` not work?

Comment: @Rajesh `const` is not hoisted.

Comment: where is `connections` coming from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: @evolutionxbox OP wishes to avoid `for...in`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: This question is a little vague. There are a number of ways you can iterate an object without `for..in`: `Object.values`, `Object.entries` or `Object.keys` with `for..of` or `forEach` or `reduce`. The real question is do you understand why `for..in` is *semantically different* than those options and do you need `for..in` for your logic to function correctly?

Comment: @Roberrrt - I don't think I suggested using `for...in`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Very correct! But all the answers in your duplicate notification state the `for...in` solution.

Comment: @Roberrrt that they do! The answer I specifically meant was http://stackoverflow.com/a/18202926/989920

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your goal alone is to avoid errors in your ESLint, i'd suggest using `Object.keys(obj).forEach()` I usually go with this approach in my own projects.

Pseudo-example:

```
Object.keys(groups).forEach(key => {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(groups[key]) === '[object Object]') {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(groups[key], 'users')) {
            count += groups[key].users.length;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank, it work perfectly. However to prevent ESLint, you should change "Object.keys(groups).forEach(key => {" to "Object.keys(groups).forEach((key) => {"

Comment: Arrow scoped parameters do not require parenthesis when single: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

It's neater to do it your way though, ++!

Answer (score 3):

Here are three possible ways of solving this depending on what part of the map you need, the keys, the values or both the key/value pairs.

If you need not only the key, but the value in the map you might choose:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  // ...
}
```

If you only need the keys:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
  // ...
}
```

Finally, if you only need the values, but not the keys you can use:

```
for (const value of Object.values(object)) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a single line for checking and counting.

```
let count = Object.keys(groups).reduce((r, key) =>
    r + (('users' in groups[key]) && groups[key].users.length || 0), 0);
```

Comment: Btw, you better use `'users' in groups[key]` (instead of `groups[key].hasOwnProperty('users')`) since otherwise semantics of the code is different.

Answer (score 0):

I like to implement an `it` helper function to iterate objects:

```
function* it(obj) {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      yield [key, obj[key]];
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can iterate like so:

```
for (const [key, value] of it(obj)) {
  if ({}.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]' &&
      value.hasOwnProperty('users')) {
      count += connections[key].users.length;
    }
}
```

While this method still uses `for..in`, it's now contained in one function, and you can make a single exception in your ESLint file for it. Then you don't need to use it ever again.