# how can I remove the quote or pass this string as normal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

```
events: "[{id:"3",title:"activity",start:"2017-03-11 00:00:00",allDay:true},{id:"4",title:"nutrition",start:"2017-03-11 00:00:00",allDay:true}]"
```

how can I remove the quote or pass this string as normal array in angularjs2?

Answer (score 2):

It's a JSON string. just use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and you'll get array of objects.

Comment: it will treat as object array. I just need it to be ordinary array

Comment: @maricejuguilon
Use map then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here, the string in events object is not a valid JSON. So u can't use `JSON.Parse` here. For valid JSON `key` should be wrapped in double quote eg: `{id:...}` should be `{"id":...}`

```
let input = {
     events: '[{id:"3",title:"activity",start:"2017-03-11 00:00:00",allDay:true},{id:"4",title:"nutrition",start:"2017-03-11 00:00:00",allDay:true}]'
};

let dataToSend = Object.assign({}, input);

dataToSend.events = eval(dataToSend.events);

console.log(dataToSend);
```

[image: output]

Since, your input sting is still a valid javascript object you can use `eval` method for conversion. Here I used `object.assign` to create a copy of your input. So, any modification to `dataToSend` will not affect your actual input object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = {
     events: '[{id:"3",title:"activity",start:"2017-03-11 00:00:00",allDay:true},{id:"4",title:"nutrition",start:"2017-03-11 00:00:00",allDay:true}]'
};

eval(obj.events);
```

[image]