# Which more elegant way iterate values from object in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have object in `redux` store

```
  `{455:{id:'455',name'test'},456:{id:'456',name:'test2},457:{id:'457',name'test3'},...}`.
```

At now I iterate values with method Object.keys. Have any more elegant method for this case? 
Many Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of using `Object.keys` to map over the object, you can use `Object.values()` that returns an array of  values and then map over them like

```js
var obj = {
  '455': {
    id: '455',
    name:'test'
  },
  '456': {
    id: '456',
    name: 'test2'
  },
  '457': {
    id: '457',
    name:'test3'
  }
}
Object.values(obj).map((val) => console.log(val))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)