# React + Redux - Reducer substate is not a object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the below data set Json file.

Upon ajax retrieval of the json file, i called the following reducer.

```
export default function clientProfile(state={}, action) {

    switch(action.type) {

        case GET_CLIENT_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload;

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

I would like to use reverse() and .map on this.state.client.notes however I'm keep getting undefined or null error. turn out when I do the following...

```
console.log(typeof this.state.client); //returns object
console.log(typeof this.state.client.notes); //returns undefined
```

I've make sure i return the json file in the correct format(hopefully) but i don't understand why the nested state is not an object but undefined. **Anyway to fix this so I can use the .reverse() and .map function, or is this working as intended? If it's working intended is there an alternative other than creating a separate reducer. I want the notes to be under the client state.**

```
    {
    "customerId": "34",
    "agentId": "1",
    "createdDate": "1510223892",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "mobile": "123456789",
    "address": "Something email here",
    "notes": {
        "0": {
            "noteId": "1",
            "customerId": "34",
            "createdBy": "1",
            "created": "1510316194",
            "note": "add something"
        },
        "1": {
            "noteId": "2",
            "customerId": "34",
            "createdBy": "1",
            "created": "1510316527",
            "note": "add something"
        },
        "2": {
            "noteId": "3",
            "customerId": "34",
            "createdBy": "1",
            "created": "1510317177",
            "note": "add new thing"
        },
        "3": {
            "noteId": "4",
            "customerId": "34",
            "createdBy": "1",
            "created": "1510318448",
            "note": "something"
        },
        "4": {
            "noteId": "5",
            "customerId": "34",
            "createdBy": "1",
            "created": "1510318476",
            "note": "this would be note number 5, lets see whether we can get something from this."
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for figuring out, and if i put console.log in render() i did get it returned as object. I'm a stuck because i also referre to this link

[map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

so I have the following codes insider render()

```
//$.map(this.props.client.notes, function(note, key) { //This works, but i cannot use reverse()

//Object.keys(this.props.client.notes).map(function(key, note) { //this doesn't work and return error


Object.keys(this.props.client.notes).map(function(key, index) {

 return (
    <li key={key}>

    <div>Key: {key} | Note_id: {this.props.client.notes[index].noteId} AND Note_content: {this.props.client.notes[index].note}</div>
    </li>
```

);

Now we figure out it's an object, but the code above still don't work.
If i can figure out the data type of the client state, then i can know what to do.

in the mean time, the aboves return following error
×

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Updated: Codes with condition
Following answers below I updated my codes, created a function of printNote() and put {this.printNote} inside render.

I can see the console log of all the keys, however, it's not being rendered on screen.

```
printNote() {
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(this.props.client.notes);

        let notes = this.props.client.notes;
        console.log('notes',notes);
        if(notes) {
            console.log('in if ');
             Object.keys(notes).map(function(key, index) {


                    console.log(key);
                    return (
                            <li key={key}>
                                <div>Key: {key} | Note_id: {notes[index].noteId} AND Note_content: {notes[index].note}</div>
                            </li>


                    );

                })

            }
        }
```

Comment: first of all you can't use `.map` on `notes` as it isn't an `array` but an `object`. and where is the `clent` key coming from? i don't see it in your json file, is this the name of the `reducer`?

Comment: yes it is the reducer. sorry I need your help again. It's the initial stage i need to get everything right.

Comment: show the code where you try to enter the `notes` with this line `console.log(typeof this.state.client.notes);` my bet is that you try accessing it before the fetch is done and you get the initial state (which is an empty object)

Comment: oh u r right, i put it in Render() and it shows it as Object. Should i change the question? How to change the object into array.

Comment: your question is "__why client.notes returns undefined__".  well you got an answer to this. as for how to change your data shape this could be a new question but i'm sure there is already an answer for this so all you need to do is search for it

Comment: there is a reason why I'm asking this because of my updated codes above can u take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the code where you are trying to access the object:

```
this.state.client.notes
```

But my bet is that you are trying to access it before the fetch operation (whic is asynchronous) is finished, hence you get the initial state of the `client` reducer which is the empty object.

As for using `.map` on `notes` this won't work because `.map` belongs to the [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and `notes` is an object not an array.

**Edit**
As a  followup to your update.

This a simple case where the  `render` method runs before you get any data back from the server.
When you want to render data that is fetched async, you should do it conditionally.

For example:

```
const { client } = this.props; // just destructuring the object for shorter lines
client.notes && Object.keys(client.notes).map(function(key, index) {

      return ( < li key = {
            key
          } >

          < div > Key: {
            key
          } | Note_id: {
            this.props.client.notes[index].noteId
          }
          AND Note_content: {
            this.props.client.notes[index].note
          } < /div> < /li>
```

The map line will only execute if `client.notes` will return a truthy value ([these are the falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy))

Comment: Please refer to my updated codes, i'm showing how i'm accessing it. It works if i use ajax $.map function

Comment: i've changed my codes to yours but it's not rendering though it shows in console.

Comment: I assume in Redux, when the Reducer is called, the states get updated and it should auto rerender but it doesn't.

Comment: it appears if i call {printNote} in render() it doesn't render, but if i put the whole function inside render, it works. Weird behavior.