# React with Typescript: property map is missing for type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to js/ts but experienced in C#. 
Now I'm learning React and want to use typescript.
I try to add types to this demo project: https://github.com/bradtraversy/projectmanager/tree/master/src .

Code so far:

```
export interface IProjectItem {
  title: string;
  category: string;
}

export interface IProjects {  
  projects : {
    [index: number]: IProjectItem;  
  };
}


class App extends React.Component<object,IProjects> {

  constructor(props: IProjects) {
    super(props);

  this.state = {
    projects: [
    {
      title: 'Business Website',
      category: 'Web Design'
    },
    ....
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div className="App">
        MyApp
        <Projects projects={ this.state.projects }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Projects extends React.Component<IProjects,object> {    

  render() {    

    if (this.props.projects)
    {
      this.props.projects.map( project => { //ERROR Property map not found for type [index:number]
        console.log(project);
      });
    }
    console.log(this.props);

    return (      
      <div className="projects">
        All Projects
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously the .map() function is not found. I think I have to change the used interfaces/types, but what is the right one?

Comment: It should be `projects: IProjectItem[]` I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspected, the issue is with your type definitions - in particular, this one:

```
export interface IProjects {  
  projects : {
    [index: number]: IProjectItem;  
  };
}
```

What this is saying is, 'an object that implements `IProjects` will contain `projects`, which is an object that can be indexed with numbers'. Note that an object that can be indexed with numbers is *not* the same thing as an array, and will not have any of the array prototype methods like `map`!

This, on  the other hand, *will* define it as an array:

```
export interface IProjects {  
  projects: IProjectItem[];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.! What  I thought  is, that [index: number]: IProjectItem; would result in something similar to c#'s "IDictionary<number, IprojectItem>" which implements IDictionary down the  down the inheritance hierarchy - Beginner's mistake.

Comment: @Tobias: If you did want to create a dictionary of numbers to objects, ` `[index: number]: IProjectItem` *is* probably how you'd want to do it - however, you can't `map` over objects in JS without a little bit of boilerplate  - see this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays

Answer (score 2):

You are using `this.props.projects.map`;

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) is for array `[]`.

But your variable `projects` is a JSON Object;

```
projects : {
    [index: number]: IProjectItem;  
  };
```

Change its type. Maybe

```
project: any[]// you will have a generic array object
```

Or

```
project: IProjectItem[] // you will have an array containing items of "IProjectItem"
```