# shorthand for arrow-functions for object property names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

when I have:

```
const foo = 1;
```

I can set a shorthand for object property names

```
const bar = {foo}
```

thats the same like

```
const bar = {foo: foo} // bar will be {foo: 1}
```

is there a shorthand when I have a const with an arrow function?

```
const foo = () => 1
```

i have to set it like this, but its uncool

```
const bar = {foo: foo()}
```

I would like to do it like this or something thats shorter

```
const bar = {foo()}  //bar should be {foo: 1} but this will fail
```

Comment: No, there's no syntax which would make it shorter, but this looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to do? Do you have a lot of such functions? Where do they come from?

Comment: There's no such syntax. This operation isn't in demand. It's just a coincidence that a function has same name as property.

Comment: I just would like to have the same benefit like in the const only example. there was an answer 5 seconds ago and it was exactly what I was looking for. will it come back? :D

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer), there's no syntax for this.

[image]

In your case `ObjectLiteral` must resolve to `{ PropertDefinitionList }`, which must resolve to `PropertyDefinition`. Now what could `PropertyDefinition` be?

It can't be `IdentifierReference` - that's your first example: `{f}`.

`CoverInitializedName` doesn't really fit either. That would look like `{f = AssignmentExpression}` where `AssignmentExpression` is defined [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators).

`PropertyName: AssignmentExpression` is the conventional syntax: `{f: 1}`

`MethodDefinition`lets you do `{f(){ return 1; }};`, but that again isn't what you want.

Looks like the verdict is no.

Comment: Imho this is a missing feature. But thanks for looking into the formal specs and clearing out why its not possible in the way I would like to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry is already there. `{foo}` is equivalent to `{foo: () => 1 }`, i.e. an object containing a property foo which is a function. E.g. you could then call it like this if you wanted:

```
bar.foo();
```

Your request seems to be for new syntax that instead calls `foo` and populates `bar.foo` with the result. **There's no such syntax**. What if `foo` takes arguments? What if `foo` is asynchronous (you'd want to use `await` then)? How did you end up with functions with the same name as properties? Without a demonstrated use-case, it's hard to see any value in optimizing for this pattern.

Shorter isn't always more readable.

If you have a set of functions dedicated to providing the results for a set of same-named properties, you could perhaps construct something, using a [mapObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829074/918910) helper, like this:

```js
const mapObj = (o, f) => Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(o).map(k => ({[k]: f(o[k])})));

const foo = () => 1;
const fum = () => 2;

let bar = mapObj({foo, fum}, f => f());

console.log(JSON.stringify(bar));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot that there are also [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) possible with arrow functions.

so if you like the benefit of this shorthand you can do

```
const foo = (() => 1)()
const bar = {foo}
```

downside: you need an IIFE

Comment: which is just setting foo to 1

Comment: Why not just do `const foo = 1`?

Comment: its just an example for a dummy function. the function in real life is more complex

Comment: @Luca well, I suppose you can have a non trivial function...but the IIFE is still unnecessary - just do the operations and assign the result to a variable, no need to make a new function just so you execute it on the same line and discard it.

Comment: The answers are as good as the question is. Why would you need IIFE in ES6 in a situation like this one? We already have blocks to create nested scopes.

Comment: long story short: the situation is more complex in general because I have lots of dynamic objects and I was looking for a solution to avoid the `bar = {foo:foo}` problem. It will make the code more readable with a shorthand solution and makes it easier to maintanance the code when something will change from my API. the answer is not really from myself. there was a user and posted it here but the answer was deleted quickly.