# AngularFire Firebase transform array from observable

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I use angular CLI, angularFire and Firebase.

I have this data in realdatabase :

[image]
I get data from firebase with an observale :

//Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from '../models/patient.model';
import {PPS } from '../models/pps.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PPSsService {
ppss: AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {this.ppss = database.list('ppss');}

getPPSByPatientid(Patientid: string){
return this.database.list('/ppss', ref => ref.orderByChild("Patientid").equalTo(Patientid)).valueChanges();
}  
}
```

// component.ts

```
export class PpsComponent implements OnInit {

 patientid: string;
 patientToDisplay;
 diagnosticsToDisplay;
 ppssToDisplay;
 traitement: string;
 data1: any[];
 config1: GanttChartConfig;
 elementId1: string;

constructor( 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private location: Location,
    private patientsService: PatientsService,
    private diagnosticsService: DiagnosticsService,
    private ppssService: PPSsService,
    private router: Router, 
    public dialog: MatDialog, 
    ){ }


  ngOnInit() {

   this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
   this.patientid = urlParameters['id']; });
   this.patientToDisplay = this.patientsService.getSinglePatient(this.patientid);
   this.diagnosticsToDisplay = this.diagnosticsService.getDiagnosticByPatientid(this.patientid);
   this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getPPSByPatientid(this.patientid);
 console.log(this.ppssToDisplay);

 this.data1 = [[ 'traitement','start', 'end'],
   [ 'Chirurgie',  new Date(2017, 3, 29), new Date(2017, 3, 30)],
   [ 'Chimiothérapie', new Date(2017, 2, 4),  new Date(2018, 2, 4)],
   [ 'Radiothérapie',   new Date(2017, 2, 4),  new Date(2018, 2, 4)]];

    this.config1 = new GanttChartConfig('', '', '',new Date (),new Date ());
    this.elementId1 = 'myGanttChart';
}
```

And i can display data in my tamplate...

But now i need in my component.ts an array like that :

```
this.ppssToDisplay = [['typetraitement', 'traitement','datedebut', 'datefin']]
```

I try to replace data1 by your code but i have an error ppssToDisplay.map is not a fonction...

Comment: Try This `this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getPPSByPatientid(this.patientid).subscribe((dataFromDb) => {
 return [ [ dataFromDb.typetraitement, dataFromDb.traitement, dataFromDb.datedebut,  dataFromDb.datefin ] ]
})`

Comment: error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
this.ppssToDisplay.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)) 
// [['typetraitement', 'traitement','datedebut', 'datefin'], ...] 

this.ppssToDisplay.map(obj => Object.values(obj))
// [["-LFw...", "2018-06-...", "2018-06...", ....],...]
```

You might also be interested to take a look at this previously answered question [about `.map()` for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays).

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, you can also do something like this:

```
let interestingFields = ['typetraitement', 'traitement','datedebut', 'datefin'];
this.ppssToDisplay.map(obj => interestingFields.map(field => obj[field]))
// only the values of your defined fields
```

Comment: I try to integrate your answer instead of data1, do you think it's the right path?

Comment: Did you import the `.map()` operator from `RxJS`? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Comment: yes, i think i write this : import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

Comment: Try to replace it with the import from my comment. Or change the code to `this.ppssToDisplay.pipe(map(obj => interestingFields.map(field => obj[field])))`

Comment: You should also take a look at [the changes between RxJS 5 and 6](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)

Comment: ok thanks. I have work ! Maybe this can help you and me, i try to follow this tutoriel http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/10/12/using-google-charts-in-angular-4-project-part-2/

Comment: With"this.data2 =this.ppssToDisplay.pipe(map(obj => interestingFields.map(field => obj[field])));
console.log(this.data2);" this.data2 is an observable you can help me again please ?