# Object version of mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

> Duplicate of: [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

How do i map or iterate through an object where the values is another object as such:

```
[{
    "id":2,
    "name":"Jane Smith",
    "position":"Cook",
    "applied":"02/08/16",
    "experience":4,
    "availability":{
        "M":1,
        "T":1,
        "W":1,
        "Th":1,
        "F":0,
        "S":0,
        "Su":0
    },
    "questions": [{
        "text":"Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
        "answer":"Yes"
    }]
},
...(2 other objects with the same format)....
]
```

I need to access the `availability` object

Comment: It's a bit unclear what behavior you are looking for. Perhaps you could provide an example output, or some pseudocode illustrating what you're trying to do.

Comment: Tell us what you want as a final output. `map or iterate through an object` can mean a lot of things.

Comment: @jered currently I am mapping through the array with these 3 objects in them and rendering them to the screen, however I cannot render the availability section and questions section because they are formatted different

Comment: @Berheet Are you asking how to convert the structure of the _availability_ objects inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a list of availability objects.

```
const availabilityObjects = objects.map(object => object.availability)
```

Will do it. Code snippet follows:

```js
const objects =  [{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Jane Smith",
   "position": "Cook",
   "applied": "02/08/16",
   "experience": 4,
   "availability": {
    "M": 1,
    "T": 1,
    "W": 1,
    "Th": 1,
    "F": 0,
    "S": 0,
    "Su": 0
   },
   "questions": [{
    "text": "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
    "answer": "Yes"
   }]
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Jane Smith",
   "position": "Cook",
   "applied": "02/08/16",
   "experience": 4,
   "availability": {
    "M": 1,
    "T": 1,
    "W": 1,
    "Th": 1,
    "F": 0,
    "S": 0,
    "Su": 0
   },
   "questions": [{
    "text": "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
    "answer": "Yes"
   }]
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Jane Smith",
   "position": "Cook",
   "applied": "02/08/16",
   "experience": 4,
   "availability": {
    "M": 1,
    "T": 1,
    "W": 1,
    "Th": 1,
    "F": 0,
    "S": 0,
    "Su": 0
   },
   "questions": [{
    "text": "Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
    "answer": "Yes"
   }]
  }
 ]
 
 console.log(objects.map(object => object.availability))
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that there is no guarantee of the order of an object's keys, so there is no perfectly consistent way to iterate over them. However, you can use the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to iterate over the enumerable properties of an object. You can use that to basically iterate through they key/value pairs of an objects and do something with them.

```
const availability = {
    "M":1,
    "T":1,
    "W":1,
    "Th":1,
    "F":0,
    "S":0,
    "Su":0
};
for (const key in availability) {
    console.log(key, availability[key]);
}

// Output:
/*
  M 1
  T 1
  W 1
  Th 1
  F 0
  S 0
  Su 0
*/
```

Since it is unclear exactly how you want to use the data I can't provide any more detail than that but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` equivalent of object is `Object.keys()` and `Object.entries()`
It is a feature introduced in ES7

```
    const data = [{
    "id":2,
    "name":"Jane Smith",
    "position":"Cook",
    "applied":"02/08/16",
    "experience":4,
    "availability":{
        "M":1,
        "T":1,
        "W":1,
        "Th":1,
        "F":0,
        "S":0,
        "Su":0
    },
    "questions": [{
        "text":"Have you ever been convicted of a felony?",
        "answer":"Yes"
    }]
}
 ]

    console.log(Object.entries(data[0].availability));
    console.log(Object.keys(data[0].availability));
```

Check this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
For your data if you have more than one object then you can first iterate through the array first using `array.map()` and use `Object.entries()` inside `map()`

Comment: You might want to change the first sentence. `Array.map` is not equivalent to `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` (they do different things). In fact there is no equivalent method to `Array.map` on `Object` at all. Only something like `o.entries().map(f).reduce((result, [key, value]) => { result[key] = value; return result}, {})` would be roughly equivalent in that it maps the elements and returns a new object.

Comment: @FK82 By equivalent I mean to say you can traverse array by using map() method and if you want to traverse object then you can refer Object.keys() and Object.entries().

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. The way you express it is not correct though, the semantics of `Array.map` are the following: _"creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."_ ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)). Neither `Object.keys` nor `Object.entries` do that on their own. That's why I'm saying that they are not equivalent. You can combine them with other functions to create something comparable to `Array.map` for objects though.