# Console log not logging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this piece of code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  CURRENCY_RATE, 
  CURRENCY_FETCHING, 
  CURRENCY_ERROR
 } from './type.js';

import {
  CurrencyRateLink
} from '../urls.js';
import {currencyDetails} from './currencyDetails'


export const CurrencyRate = (selectedCurrency) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: CURRENCY_FETCHING})
    axios.get(CurrencyRateLink).then((response) => {
      let Currency = []
      if ( selectedCurrency != "USD") {
      let CurrencyRates = Object.keys(response.data.rates)
        for (let i=0; i<CurrencyRates.length; i++) {
           if (selectedCurrency == CurrencyRates[i]) {

             console.log("inside If condition")
            let currencySymbol = currencyDetails[selectedCurrency][symbol]
             console.log(currencySymbol)

              Currency.push({
              currencyName : CurrencyRates[i],
              currencyPrice : response.data.rates[selectedCurrency]
              })
           }
        }

      }
    return (
    dispatch({
      //Dispatching Redux Action
    })
  )}).catch((error) => dispatch({
      //Error Handling
   }))
  }
```

Here this statement isn't logging anything

```
console.log(currencySymbol)
```

but a statement just above it is logging in console log

```
console.log("inside If condition")
```

**[Question:]** What could be doing wrong?

**[Note:]** When I do something like  `let currencySymbol = currencyDetails[selectedCurrency]` there `currencyDetails[selectedCurrency]` may not exist but then shouldn't it log undefined or throw an error instead of not logging anything?

**[Update:]** I am working on React-native

Comment: is there just an empty line in the log? Maybe the field is there but empty (i.e. not null but just containing the empty string `""`). Try using the debugger to look at the variable values, or do something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(currencyDetails[selectedCurrency]));` and see what properties are inside the selectedCurrency, and what values they have

Comment: Rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, *turn on the lights* by using the powerful debugger built into your browser to step through the code statement by statement, inspecting your variables while execution is stopped, etc. Search for "<your browser here> developers tools" to learn how to use the debugger. Perhaps the code *is* throwing an error but something is catching and swallowing it.

Comment: do you have any sort of console filters enabled ?

Comment: @apokryfos Nope

Comment: @ADyson that doesn't work either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Trying that :)

Comment: "doesn't work" means what exactly? What output do you get? Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(currencyDetails));` instead. Try `alert(JSON.stringify(currencyDetails));` instead even. Or better still as T.J. Crowder said...**use the debugger**

Comment: @ADyson I mean, my console isn't logging that as well. I can't try `alert(JSON.stringify(currencyDetails));` since it is `react-native` but still thanks, I am trying what T.J Crowder said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currencyDetails[selectedCurrency][symbol]` may throws an error as `currencyDetails[selectedCurrency]` is undefined. try to log that first.

If you are using promise: when an error happened it will call your catch block and not reporting any undefined error in the console.

```js
const promise = new Promise((accept, reject) => {
  accept(1);
})

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('Inside then');
  const data = {};
  console.log('Should throw an error ' + data['abc']['def']);
  console.log('After throw');
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('Error will be happening here');
});
```

Comment: Updated my code 
Also, It isn't even throwing any errors  :)

Comment: As the OP mentions in the edit at the end of the question, if that were happening, he/she would be seeing an error in the console (unless of course something is catching and swallowing errors). *(not my downvote, and it seems harsh)*

Comment: Update the answer with explanation. You need to verify if your catch block is called or not.

Comment: @DanielTran I simply did a console.log in `catch` statement to realize that I should've done something like this ["symbol"]. Though I still expected it to throw an error as you previously pointed it out.

Comment: Yeah it did throw an error to your catch block. You  just ignored it

Answer (score 2):

You might getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property XXX of undefined` but not visible on your react native cli.
if `currencyDetails[selectedCurrency] == undefined`, then there will be above error situation

try below code:

```
let currencySymbol = (currencyDetails[selectedCurrency]) ? currencyDetails[selectedCurrency][symbol] : null
console.log('result', currencySymbol)
```

At lease you should get `result null`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this when working with React-Native and Expo... I found that sometimes my `console.log()` would not appear in the terminal, but then I found that they could always be viewed through the Chrome developer tools during remote debugging.

If you are remote debugging check the console output of the browser. If you are not remote debugging, consider it.

Comment: Thanks @Joey for answer. I am using chrome  developer tools and it isn’t appearing there as well :)

Comment: as a shot in the dark, try to `console.log(typeof currencySymbol)`

Answer (score 0):

**SIDE NOTE - not directly related to question (title) but code structure**

This statement

```
  let CurrencyRates = Object.keys(response.data.rates)
```

gives you **only array of keys**, you can't use it (`i` index) to access values (response.data.rates) ;)

Why not to use simple `map` or `for in`? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722/6124657) you can do sth like:

```
const rates = response.data.rates
Object.keys(rates).map(function(key, index) {
  if( selectedCurrency == key) {
    Currency.push({
          currencyName : key,
          currencyPrice : rates[key]
        })
  }
});
```

but even this isn't neccessary as **you can just use property name to find value**:

```
const rates = response.data.rates
if( rates[selectedCurrency] !== undefined ) {
    Currency.push({
          currencyName : selectedCurrency,
          currencyPrice : rates[selectedCurrency]
        })
}
```

**Problem with `currencySymbol = currencyDetails[selectedCurrency][symbol]` can't be solved without knowledge about `currencyDetails` structure** and expectations.