# How to convert an object into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

So I've got some state that is an object which looks like this

```
object:{
  foo: Array[3]
  bar: Array[6]
}
```

And The amount of entries inside the object may change, it could have 3 arrays, it could have 10. It needs to be dynamic
I've got to display those as counts (in a pie chart) which accepts the data to look like this, with data being the prop inside the JSX tag

```
data:{[
  {x:foo, y:foo.length},
  {x:bar, y:bar.length}
]}
```

x outputs as the name and y outputs as the number (not a percent, the lib works it out for me)

I've tried using some examples on here such as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays) but I'm just not getting it

Preference for ES6 syntax &
I'm using [Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) for my graphing lib if you're interested

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what the question is

Comment: Can you edit the question and post a Minimal Complete and Verifiable example of what you have tried so far (which is causing you problems)?

Comment: The answers there should work just fine, how exactly did you try implementing them? For example `return {x:key, y:object[key].length}` should work in a map of the object keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let obj = {foo : [1,2,3], bar : [1,2,3,4,5,6]};
let data = Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => ({x:k, y:v.length}));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @AlistairHardy - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could even simply use map with keys: (to make support for ie)

```js
const obj = {foo : [1,2,3], bar : [1,2,3,4,5,6]};
const d = Object.keys(obj).map(el => ({x:el, y:obj[el].length}));
console.log(d);
```