# TypeError: prop.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Help please...here's what my data looks like in the console. The data is being passed from the parent component as a prop. I want to map through this data to receive the values for my table. I have already received the table's headers by assigning the headers the following value.

const tableHead = Object.keys(props.user.referrerPromos[1]);

```
User
       referrerPromos: Array(8)
    0:
    company: {name: "BeatnikTech2", __typename: "PromoCompany"}
    description: "Use the referral link or code to get 100% of everything everyday"
    ref_code: "102039PW"
    ref_link: "https://www.vipkidteachers.com/mkt/landing/personal?referralToken=870a75547ac15f64bcfbb89c1d6c87e1&refereeId=9515945"
    __typename: "Promo"
    __proto__: Object
    1: {company: {…}, ref_code: "102039PWs", ref_link: "www.vipkidteachers.com/mkt/landing/personal?referr…70a75547ac15f64bcfbb89c1d6c87e1&refereeId=9515945", description: "Use the referral link or code to get 100% of everything everyday", __typename: "Promo"}
    2: {company: {…}, ref_code: "SABRI0029", ref_link: "Link: https://www.vipkidteachers.com/mkt/landing/p…70a75547ac15f64bcfbb89c1d6c87e1&refereeId=9515945", description: "Teach ESL in China. It's the Gift that keeps on giving", __typename: "Promo"}
    3: {company: {…}, ref_code: " https://refer.sprint.com/Sbl8RI4-Aga8TZE", ref_link: "https://refer.sprint.com/Sbl8RI4-Aga8TZE", description: "Join the best cell phone network. Use my code and get the awesomest discount ever", __typename: "Promo"}
    4: {company: {…}, ref_code: "sabrina105", ref_link: "https://www.cambly.com/en/tutors?referralCode=sabrina105", description: "Join the best cell phone network. Use my code and get the awesomest discount ever", __typename: "Promo"}
    5: {company: {…}, ref_code: "amazonprime179", ref_link: "https://www.amazon.com/en/tutors?referralCode=sabrina711", description: "This code doesn't actually work. Amazon Prime disc…tinued their referral progams in octobeer of 2017", __typename: "Promo"}
    6: {company: {…}, ref_code: "KDLDQQB", ref_link: "https://cash.me/app/KDLDQQB", description: "Join Cash App and get $5.00 ! Send and recieve mon… an instant while getting 5 of your next purchase", __typename: "Promo"}
    7: {company: {…}, ref_code: "(2)KDLDQQB", ref_link: "(2)https://cash.me/app/KDLDQQB", description: "Join Cash App and get $5.00 ! Send and recieve mon… an instant while getting 5 of your next purc
```

I have tried using:

```js
const tableData = Object.values(props.user.referrerPromos);
const tableHead = [Object.values(props.user.referrerPromos)]
const tableHead = [`${Object.values(props.user.referrerPromos)}`];
```

among others, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Below is the code where the map function is invoked:

```
         {tableData.map((prop, key) => {
        return (
          <TableRow key={key}>
            {prop.map((prop, key) => {
              return (
                <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
                  {prop}
                </TableCell>
              );
            })}
          </TableRow>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: Can you show us the part where you tried using `map` function?

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided I see few mistakes and I've modified your code a bit and pasted below.

```js
const tableData = props.user.referrerPromos;
const tableHead = Object.keys(props.user.referrerPromos[1]);

{tableData.map((promo, key) => {
  return (
    <TableRow key={key}>
      {tableHead.forEach((prop, key) => {
        return (
          <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} key={key}>
            {promo[prop]}
          </TableCell>
        );
      })}
    </TableRow>
  );
})}
```

To access referrerPromos and assign it to tableData

```js
const tableData = props.user.referrerPromos;
```

To iterate all properties in an object, use previously assigned variable tableHead and iterate over it to get all keys you want in the same order.

```js
tableHead.forEach((prop, key) => {
   ...
   {promo[prop]}
   ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I used .forEach() and Objects.values()...then .map()

Answer (score 0):

`map()` is only defined for arrays. In your first line of code, `tableData` is an array, therefore you can use map on it.

However, it doesn't seem to be that `prop` is an array. Judging from your code, `prop` is a plain Object, therefore you cannot use `map()` on it.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays) to see how you could use map on an Object.