# How can I rename or map multiple keys to a new key name?

Tags: node.js, json

I am working with JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Person1",
        "a_miles": "110 mi"
    },
    {
        "name": "Person2",
        "b_miles": "22 mi"
    },
    {
        "name": "Person3",
        "a_miles": "552 mi"
    }
]
```

I need to rename a_miles or b_miles to "total" , but can't seem to get .map() to work since it won't allow multiple keys to 1 final key. Each item with have either A or B as well.

This is what I tried so far:

```
    .data(function(data) {
        console.log('checking for KMs');
        for(key in data) {
            console.log(key);
            if(data[key].includes(' km')){
                console.log('KM found, deleting %s', key)
                delete data[key];
            }
        }
        //console.log(data)
        savedData.push(data);
    })
    .done(function() {
        var formattedJson = savedData.map(({
            name,
            a_miles:total,
            b_miles:total
        }) => ({
            name,
            total

        }));
```

Maybe I'm over complicating things, I just need to have a total key/value that replaces a or b so it's consistent through the whole array result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can apply a .map to an object, as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays).
Here is an example:

```
a.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).map( key => {
    if (key.match('_miles')){
        obj['total'] = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
    }
  })
})
console.log(a);
// [ { name: 'Person1', total: '110 mi' },
//  { name: 'Person2', total: '22 mi' },
//  { name: 'Person3', total: '552 mi' } ]
```

Where *a* is the array you proposed. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your destructuring, If you ***JUST*** want `a_miles` or `b_miles` you can use your syntax also just add an `OR` between them:

```
.done(function () {
  const formattedJson = savedData.map(({
    name,
    a_miles,
    b_miles
  }) => ({
    name,
    total: a_miles || b_miles

  }))
});
```