# Get count of every array inside nested JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a nested json data like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "COUNTRIES": [
            {
                "COUNTRY": "INDIA",
                "CITIES": [
                    {
                        "CITY": "BANGALORE",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "amazon",
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "5"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "6"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "7"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "CITY": "DELHI",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "amazon",
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "5"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "6"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "7"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "COUNTRY": "UNITED KINGDOM",
                "CITIES": [
                    {
                        "CITY": "BIRMINGHAM",
                        "STORE": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

which i have to modify and count of each array at each level resulting in something like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "COUNTRIES": [
            {
                "COUNTRY": "INDIA",
                "CITIES": [
                    {
                        "CITY": "BANGALORE",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "AMAZON",
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "5"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "6"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "7"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "DEVICE_CNT": 7,
                                "APPLIANCES_CNT": 35
                            }
                        ],
                        "STORE_CNT": 1,
                        "DEVICE_CNT": 7,
                        "APPLIANCES_CNT": 35
                    },
                    {
                        "CITY": "DELHI",
                        "STORE": [],
                        "STORE_CNT": 0
                    }
                ],
                "CITY_CNT": 2,
                "STORE_CNT": 1,
                "DEVICE_CNT": 7,
                "APPLIANCES_CNT": 35
            },
            {
                "COUNTRY": "UNITED KINGDOM",
                "CITIES": [
                    {
                        "CITY": "BIRMINGHAM",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "M&S",
                                "LATTITUDE": 52.486243,
                                "LONGITUDE": -1.890401,
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "4"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "APPLIANCES_CNT": 4
                                    }
                                ],
                                "DEVICE_CNT": 1,
                                "APPLIANCES_CNT": 4
                            }
                        ],
                        "STORE_CNT": 1,
                        "DEVICE_CNT": 1,
                        "APPLIANCES_CNT": 4
                    }
                ],
                "CITY_CNT": 1,
                "STORE_CNT": 1,
                "DEVICE_CNT": 1,
                "APPLIANCES_CNT": 4
            }
        ],
        "COUNTRY_CNT": 2,
        "CITY_CNT": 3,
        "STORE_CNT": 2,
        "DEVICE_CNT": 8,
        "APPLIANCES_CNT": 39
    }
}
```

I'm unable to get the total count at the upper level,for ex. at CITIES,the total count of appliances must be the total count of all appliances in BANGLORE.I'm only able to get the count at a particular level but not above it.

This is what i have done till now

```
let levels = {
  0: ["COUNTRY_CNT", "CITY_COUNT", "STORE_COUNT", "DEVICE_COUNT", "APPLIANCES_COUNT"],
  1: ["CITY_COUNT", "STORE_COUNT", "DEVICE_COUNT", "APPLIANCES_COUNT"],
  2: ["STORE_COUNT", "DEVICE_COUNT", "APPLIANCES_COUNT"],
  3: ["DEVICE_COUNT", "APPLIANCES_COUNT"],
  4: ["APPLIANCES_COUNT"]
};
let counts = {COUNTRIES:0,CITIES:0,STORE:0,DEVICE_DETAILS:0,APPLIANCES:0};
let count_mapping = {
  CITY_COUNT:"CITIES",
  STORE_COUNT:"STORE",
  DEVICE_COUNT: "DEVICE_DETAILS",
  APPLIANCES_COUNT: "APPLIANCES",
  COUNTRY_CNT:"COUNTRIES"
};
let total_count= {COUNTRIES:[],CITIES:[],STORE:[],DEVICE_DETAILS:[],APPLIANCES:[]};
  async function parse(dictionary,level) {
    console.log(dictionary);
    for (item in dictionary) {
      counts = {COUNTRIES:0,CITIES:0,STORE:0,DEVICE_DETAILS:0,APPLIANCES:0};
      for (subItem in dictionary[item]) {
        let b = item;
        if (dictionary[b]) {
          let sub = subItem;
          let main = dictionary[b][subItem];
          if (Array.isArray(dictionary[b][subItem])) {
           await parse(dictionary[b][subItem],level+1);
            if ( dictionary[b] && Array.isArray(main)){
              counts[sub]=dictionary[b][sub].length;
            }
            await add(b,dictionary,level);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function add(b,dictionary,level) {
    for(params in levels[level]){
      if(dictionary[b])
        dictionary[b][levels[level][params]] = counts[count_mapping[levels[level][params]]]
    }
  }
```

How do i get my desired output?

Answer (score 3):

You can run async-await to get the initial data as you have done.

Then you should be using a combination of `.length`, `.map()` and `.reduce()` methods on the arrays.

I have created the code below to show you how it can be done for city count and store count. You can do it similarly for other properties as well.

```js
let dictionary = {
    "datetime": "2020-01-09T11:00:01+05:30",
    "timestamp": 1578547801392,
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "COUNTRIES": [
            {
                "COUNTRY": "INDIA",
                "CITIES": [
                    {
                        "CITY": "BANGALORE",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "amazon",
                                "LATTITUDE": 12.9316666,
                                "LONGITUDE": 77.6226849,
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffc80001"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffc80002"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0602ffd00701"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0615ff600901"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0605ffd00702"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffb80b01"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffb80b02"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "CITY": "DELHI",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "amazon",
                                "LATTITUDE": 12.9316666,
                                "LONGITUDE": 77.6226849,
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffc80001"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffc80002"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0602ffd00701"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0615ff600901"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0605ffd00702"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffb80b01"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0235ffb80b02"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "COUNTRY": "UNITED KINGDOM",
                "CITIES": [
                    {
                        "CITY": "BIRMINGHAM",
                        "STORE": [
                            {
                                "STORE_NAME": "M&S",
                                "LATTITUDE": 52.486243,
                                "LONGITUDE": -1.890401,
                                "DEVICE_DETAILS": [
                                    {
                                        "POI": "POI1",
                                        "APPLIANCES": [
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "100202640001"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0106ffe0150"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0106ffe01501"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "APPLIANCE_ID": "0106ffe01503"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

};
    


let newJson = dictionary;
newJson.data.COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_CNT = newJson.data.COUNTRIES.length

newJson.data.COUNTRIES = newJson.data.COUNTRIES.map( country =>{
  country.CITY_CNT = country.CITIES.length;
  country.CITIES = country.CITIES.map(city => {
    city.STORE_CNT = city.STORE.length
    return city;
  });
  country.STORE_CNT = country.CITIES.reduce((total, city) => {  
      return total + city.STORE_CNT
  }, 0);
  return country;
});

console.log(newJson);
```

Comment: Thanks.This was very helpful.Is it possible to do this dynamically i.e. if i don't know the keys an arrays present.In my code i tried doing that recursively using for each loop?

Comment: You can do that but since they are not all arrays, map and reduce cannot be used there. You can try using some custom map function like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722/3336971 and give it a try with your recursive logic