# How to run map function in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to run map function I am trying to map function but it throws error cannot read the property of map undefined in Reactjs

I'm trying to do something like the following in React JSX component

```
const data = {
    Details: [
{       
        "id": "6f12",
        "nextPart": {
          "id": "1ae2",
          "text": "Details",
          "heading": "twice data and staff memeber",
          "checks": [
            {
              "value": "A"
            },
            {
              "value": "B"
            }
          ],
          "Types": "Error"
        },
        "conclusion": "final"
    }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `nextPart` is an object, not an array.

Comment: You're trying to use map on an object which , you can only call map on an array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays for solutions howchange your map to an array

Comment: oh @Drew Reese how should i use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nextPart` property is an `object`, not an `array`. Map works on arrays.
If your `Details` is intended to be an array of objects (which looks like it does), you can do it like this

```
{data.Details.map((item) => {
    const { text, heading, checks } = item.nextPart;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{text}</div>
        <div>{heading}</div>
        <div>
          {checks.map(({ value }) => (
            <div>{value}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
```