# map on javascript object - get the object keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

i need to map an object like this

```js
let obj = { 
    a : { value : 5, meta: "sss" },
    b : { value : 1, meta: "rrr" },
    a : { value : 6, meta: "nnn" },
}`
```

to obtain and object like this

```js
{ a: 5, b: 1, c:6}
```

I can't get the "key" as a string.

I've tried:

```js
let yyy = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return { key: obj[key].value };
});
```

But it produces an "Array" (while I need an Object) of `{key : 5}...`    with the string "key" instead of the name of the key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Answer (score 8):

You could use `.reduce`

```js
let obj = { 
    a : { value : 5, meta: "sss" },
    b : { value : 1, meta: "rrr" },
    c : { value : 6, meta: "nnn" },
}

var res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  acc[elem] = obj[elem].value;
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could get the entries and map the key and property `value` for a new object.

```js
let object = { a : { value: 5, meta: "sss" }, b : { value: 1, meta: "rrr" }, c : { value: 6, meta: "nnn" } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, { value }]) => [key, value])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this below :

Use Object.keys on your input.

```
let obj = { 'a': {value: 5, meta: "sss"},
            'b': {value: 1, meta: "rrr"},
            'c': {value: 6, meta: "nnn"},
          };

let output = {};
Object.keys(obj).map(function (item) {
    output[item] = obj[item]['value']
});
console.log(output)


Output : { a: 5, b: 1, c:6}
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array. Not fit for this case. A better alternative would be `forEach`

Answer (score 2):

Try using reduce instead of map..

```
const obj = { 
    a : { value : 5, meta: "sss" },
    b : { value : 1, meta: "rrr" },
    c : { value : 6, meta: "nnn" },
}


const res = Object.keys(obj).reduce( (res, key) => {
  res[key] = obj[key].value
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` function to achieve your result.

```
let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,k) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        [k]:obj[k].value
    };
},{})
console.log(result); // {"a":5,"b":1,"c":6}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using `for..of` loop and destructuring values

```
let obj = { 
    a : { value : 5, meta: "sss" },
    b : { value : 1, meta: "rrr" },
    c : { value : 6, meta: "nnn" },
}
const data = Object.entries(obj);
let result={};
for(let [key, {value}] of data) {
  result[key] = value;
}
console.log(result);
```