# TypeScript custom object mapping

Tags: typescript, mapping

I have a Typescript object that will look like this:

```
{
    "obj1" : { object: type1;};
    "obj2" : { object: type2;};
    "obj3" : { object: type3;};
    "obj4" : { object: type4;};
    "obj5" : { object: type5;};
}
```

I want to map it to

```
{
    "obj1" : type1;
    "obj2" : type2;
    "obj3" : type3;
    "obj4" : type4;
    "obj5" : type5;
}
```

My concern is preserving types here.

I am using typescript 3.7.2
let me know even if there is a solution in a later version.

Can anyone help ?

UPDATE ----
My problem is typing not object mapping.
I want the types of my objects to be reflected in compile time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: My problem is typing not object mapping.
I want the types of my objects to be reflected in compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
interface Foo {
  obj1: { object: string };
  obj2: { object: number };
  obj3: { object: boolean };
}

type FooMapped = { [key in keyof Foo]: Foo[key]["object"] };

const foom: FooMapped = {
  obj1: "obj1",
  obj2: 432,
  obj3: true
}
```

And a more generic solution:

```
function mapObject<R extends Record<string, { object: unknown }>>(record: R) {
  let ret: any = {};
  Object.keys(record).forEach((key) => {
    ret[key] = record[key]["object"];
  });

  return ret as {
    [key in keyof R]: R[key]["object"];
  };
}

const foo = mapObject({
  bar: { object: 412 },
  baz: { object: true }
});

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Thank you,
I could not use it in a generic way, But It did the deed.
Generic meaning make a function that do the mapping and the typing for the input object.

Comment: I added a generic function

Comment: I have another question if you would be so kind to have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101854/typescript-i-want-a-type-which-is-the-union-of-all-types-in-an-abject-properties

Comment: I have yet another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121881/using-a-type-as-a-parameter-typescript
I am really questioning if it is possible.
Have a look if you would.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look this code:

```
let objects = {
    "obj1" : { "object": "type1"},
    "obj2" : { "object": "type2"},
    "obj3" : { "object": "type3"},
    "obj4" : { "object": "type4"},
    "obj5" : { "object": "type5"},
};
for (let key of Object.keys(objects)) {
  objects[key] = objects[key]['object'];
}
console.log(objects);
```