# Typescript I want a type which is the union of all types in an abject properties

Tags: typescript, typing

I have this object

```
{
    "obj1" : type1;
    "obj2" : type2;
    "obj3" : type3;
    "obj4" : type4;
    "obj5" : type5;
}
```

I want to get a type like the following.

```
type MyType = type1 | type2 | type3 | type4 | type5;
```

I don't think the title of the question sound very good, If you would suggest a title for the question I would be grateful as well.

Comment: Please don't generate type from javascript object it's not the intend of TypeScript. First you manually define the types, then you create and type some javascript objects with them.

Comment: My intention is to reflect types not to generate them

Comment: Still the same bad reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
interface A {
  obj1: number;
  obj2: string;
  obj3: boolean;
}

type MyType = A[keyof A];
```

Where `keyof A` extracts the keys, you get `"obj1" | "obj2" | "obj3"`.
And then you can use it to index your record type `A[k]`.

Comment: He his speaking of an `object`, not an `interface`.

Comment: He has has `type1`, `type2` followed by semicolons. That's probably an interface @johannchopin.

Comment: If it's an object, you can replace with `type MyType = (typeof obj)[keyof typeof obj]`