# Using a type as a parameter Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

how to use a type as a parameter in Typescript

```
type myType = {}
const passingType = (t: Type) => {
    const x : t = {}
}

passingType(myType);
```

I get TS errors

> 't' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof t'?

and

> 'myType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

for the call

any idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Look up "typescript type parameter".

Comment: Also known as generics

Comment: I want to pass the type as a parameter to use it in an internal check,
If I pass it as a type parameter I can't make checks based on it.

Comment: What "internal check"?  Can you post a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: First I want to know if passing a type is doable or no,

Comment: second 

I want to check if T is undefined or not 
function<T>(someInput : any): T { if (T == undefined) do something; else do something else;}

Comment: Remember that Typescript's type system is compile-time only, it won't be in the javascript code in any way when compiled, so you can't compare `T` against anything inside the logic flow. You can do `typeof x === 'undefined'` or simply `x === undefined` where x is a variable, but I don't think that's what you want to do. I think we'd need more context of why you would want to do that, isn't it easier to write different functions for different types if you know it when calling the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible.

---

TypeScript's static type system (which includes your `myType` definition and type annotations) is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is emitted as JavaScript.  JavaScript is what actually runs at runtime.  At runtime, all you can access are *values*.  Type erasure means your code above becomes something like this:

```
const passingType = (t) => {
    const x = {};
};
passingType(myType);
```

There's no value named `myType` to pass to `passingType`.

And because TypeScript types don't exist as values at runtime, there is no "type of types" like what you're calling `Type`.  So this approach, as stated, is not directly possible.

---

Instead of thinking about passing a "type" to a function at runtime, which is not fruitful, it's probably best to think specifically about what you want to happen at runtime in pure JavaScript, and then write types to support that.

What would you really want to do with a "type" at runtime?  Do you want to use it to check if a value is of that type?  Then instead of passing in a type you might want to pass in a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
type Guard<T> = (x: any) => x is T;
const passingType = <T,>(t: Guard<T>) => {
    if (t(undefined)) {
        console.log("undefined IS of the guarded type T");
    }  else {
        console.log("undefined is NOT of the guarded type T");
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
function isUndefined(x: any): x is undefined {
    return typeof x === "undefined";
}

passingType(isUndefined); // undefined IS of the guarded type T

function isNumber(x: any): x is number {
    return typeof x === "number";
}
passingType(isNumber); // undefined IS NOT of the guarded type T

function isNumberOrUndefined(x: any): x is number | undefined {
    return isNumber(x) || isUndefined(x);
}

passingType(isNumberOrUndefined); // undefined IS of the guarded type T
```

Your actual use case will drive the requirements for what the argument to `passingType` should look like.  It might be a whole data structure representing various things you'd want to do with a "type" at runtime.  So even if this type guard example doesn't work for you, it's possible that something else will.

---

But again, the short answer is that TypeScript's static type system is erased and thus it is impossible to refer to its types directly at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4grgQwE4BMA8AVAfFAvFACgA8AuKBAOxAEo8cioBLAZygwG4BYAKAGMB7Cs2BQwCZs0YUA5hnDR8mADRYCwMvGTpstXDgDePKMaYAzQsAJwKKCKakQU1Woe4n3UAUP4AbCADoffmkCACJrW3sKRygASQBlKH5zYAALaGlEVBjQSDZQ6i43EwBfYwgfZmhXDxMvZl8AoJDwmzsHFCZWADkAeQwklPSoTK0c+XzCo1KoHhKeHlNrXmBGQS6AVTaox2IyShoyBhYoCPbozpqTJAhgOCQKKFyIZKgGXA+oVsiO0KL57g8MQSKSyeQEFhbH4XQpQAD0cNO2w6cUSrzSGSytk6zzYC24SwoKzWjxY3TgAFsAEYQJB7chUahHLpQCiUmlIKBXYw3O4PJ7yV7vT6hNnU2l-OZA8SSGRySAQ5jk8VIWEIpHQmIJKB9Abo4ajbI4iYYfGE4nrMns2m9JBQ867UgMw5vFlijlQAA+Godl2mPNu91JSutdKItE93shyIuxCm3AB0pBcvBVpVtvtOyc7HhiLOWdRgyeBqx4zypsB3CAA)

Answer (score 3):

Use generics instead. Type arguments have a different syntax from emitted JS arguments. For example:

```
type TheType = |
  { foo: string } |
  { bar: string };
const passingType = <T extends TheType>(obj: T) => {
    return { ...obj };
};

const result = passingType({ foo: 'foo' });
```

This results in `result`, a new object created inside the function, being typed properly as `{ foo: string }`.