# How to square all values of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

Here is an object:

```
var a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

I would need to square all values from this object and the keys to remain the same, so new object to look like this:

```
var a1 = {a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}
```

My code - I extracted the keys and the values and created two separate arrays:

```js
var a = {a:1, b: 2, c:3};
let key = Object.keys(a);
let value = Object.values(a);
v = [];
for (var i=0; i<value.length;i++){
  value[i]**2;
  v.push(value[i]**2);
}
console.log(v);
```

So here I got the array with squared values of all elements, but I don't know how to return it back to the object and get

```
{a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}
```

Comment: Do you want to alter the original object or make a new one?

Comment: espascarello Yes!

Comment: Um, that is two options.... Yes does not pick one or the other

Comment: @epascarello, but one of them is true ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @epascarello `option1 || option2 == true` :P

Comment: `value[i] = value[i] * value[i];`

Comment: Loop thorugh the object and update the keys: `for(const k in a) a[k] = a[k] ** 2`

Comment: See also [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14810506/215552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep key and value together, you could work with the entries of the object and map new pairs and build an object from the new entries.

Methods:

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get an array of all key/value pairs.
- [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), create a new object from an array with key/value pairs.
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), create a new array with the same length and different values.

```js
const
    object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, value]) => [key, value * value])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.reduce` on `Object.entries`. I.e.

```js
const a = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const result = Object.entries(a).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = value ** 2;
  return acc
}, {})
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

Object.keys(a).map(function(key, index) {
  a[key] = a[key] * a[key];
});

console.log(a)
```