# TypeError: updates.map is not a function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Widgets.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
    import { DataContext } from '../contexts/DataContext';
    
    
    const Widgets = () => {
        const {updates} = useContext(DataContext);
        console.log(updates);
        return (
            <div className="MainWidget">
                <ul>
                    {updates.map(update => {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            <li>{update.current.condition}</li>
                            <p>{update.current.temp_c}</p>
                          </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default Widgets;
```

**I'm mapping data from an API which is returning an error: `TypeError: updates.map is not a function` but its actually returning the data in the console using the `console.log()` function.**

DataContext.js
:**I'm using axios to fetch data from weatherapi.com and setting the state 'updates' with 'setUpdates' function.**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, createContext} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const DataContext = createContext();

const DataContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [updates, setUpdates] = useState({});
    const url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=931701d0de0c4d05b0b34936203011&q=London";

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res.json())
             setUpdates(res.data)
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err)
         })
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <DataContext.Provider value={{updates}}>
                {props.children}
            </DataContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}


export default DataContextProvider;
```

[image]

Comment: What are you getting in the console? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: check updates is it array or a json object.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Just added one

Comment: So it is a single object with 2 fields instead of an array. You can't iterate over it. If you expect it to be an array there is something wrong with you context

Comment: I used ([ ]) to setstate which is expecting an array, instead of ?? to expect an object.

Comment: Your initial state is indeed an empty array, but then it gets replaced with an object. It's not clear from your post where this data comes from,  if you're still struggling with this issue you might want to add `DataContext` code to your question

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Will do

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova added the DataContext.js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requesting data for only one location and the API returns you an object, not an array. You can either change your component to expect an object, or update the context provider, so it provides an array. That will looks something like:

```
const [updates, setUpdates] = useState([]);//note you want an array ([]) not an object ({})
 ...
let data = res.data
if(!data instanceof Array) data = [data] //put an object into array if needed
setUpdates(data)
```

UPDATE

In you repo make following changes:

In the DataContext you need to parse JSON response into an object, so replace

```
axios.get(url)
     .then(res => {
         setUpdates(res.data.current)
     })
```

with

```
axios.get(url)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => {
         setUpdates(res.current)
     })
```

This will mean you already have `current` in the provider and in the component you can access its fields directly, so you'll need to replace

```
 <p>{updates.current}</p>
```

with something like

```
 <p>{updates.temp_c}</p>
 <p>{updates.humidity}</p>
```

Comment: My Repo https://github.com/kelvinyelyen/weather.app

Comment: @KelvinYelyen try following the update section

Comment: Its giving res.json() is not a function

Comment: Yes, `axios` does it for you, ignore this bit, your provider is already fine!

Comment: Ow okay, but its now giving an 'undefined'

Comment: I'm not getting anything undefined https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-playground-forked-xqx80

Comment: Finally Worked!

Comment: Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but either your `updates` is an object, which means you can't map, or while your API is being called, that is undefined, which is why it crashes.

If your `update` is an object then you can do: [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

If its `undefined` while calling API, then you can do a simple check to see if its undefined and only map when it's not.

Comment: I was expecting an array instead of an object