# How to map through objects and arrays in translations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-i18next

I have 2 JSON files with my translation data -> **EN** file and **FR** file.

I am using react-i18next to handle my translations this way, which works fine, but since I am having repeatable components I need to map/loop through the translations to get the right output

**Example**

en:

```
export const EN = {
    page1: {
      section1 {
         titles: {
            title1: "title1_name",
            title2: "title2_name",
            title3: "title3_name"
          },
          buttons: {
             button1 : "button1_name",
             button2 : "button2_name",
             button3 : "button3_name",
          }
       }
       section2 { THE SAME AS SECTION 1 }
       section3 { THE SAME AS SECTION 1 }

    page2 { SAME AS PAGE 1 }
```

The same thing applies for FR file (with french translations instead)

How can achieve to mapping all e.g titles from section1 and page1. Would that be even correct to use `map()` ?

Right now my solution is just to use `{t page1.section1.0.titles.title1}` which of course print the same title everywhere -  in this case title1_name

**Current Output with using** `{t page1.section1.0.titles.title1}` :

slider1: title1_name

slider2: title1_name

slider3: title1_name

slider4: title1_name
and so on so on...

**Expected output:**

slider1: title1_name,  button1_name

slider2: title2_name,  button2_name

slider3: title4_name,  button3_name

slider4: title4_name,  button4_name

Comment: Hey Eliot, do you need `EN.page2` to be the same as `EN.page1`?

Comment: @jburtondev no, thats is just example to make it shorter - explanation of my json file structure. What I need is to print out all titles from page1 and section1 - you can see I am using { t } from useTranslation so I right now I am printing it `{t page1.section1.0.titles.title1}`but this is printing only title1_name everywhere

Comment: Sure, please add the expected output object in your question and then i'll be able to add an answer.

Comment: I updated my post, let me know if doesnt make sense

Comment: Sure, taking a look now.

Comment: Added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works, you'll need to do the translation, but this gives you access to the title object in each page and section:

```
    Object.entries(EN).map(([key,object]) => {

      Object.entries(object).map(([token, value]) => {
          console.log(`${token} : ${value}`);
          Object.keys(value).map((key, index) => {
            console.log(value[key]); // titles access here
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does print all I need in my console, although yeah, I will need to figure out the language thing.

Comment: No probs Eliot.

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over an object you'll want to use a function that gets data from your object in an array.  Traditionally that is [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), but newer versions of Javascript introduced [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which can be very helpful depending on the situation.  You can access a value from its key like `myObject[myKey]` so `Object.keys()` can work in every situation.

The current structure of your JSON file is not ideal because you have totally separate objects for `titles` and `buttons` so you can't ensure that you have the same amount of title texts as button texts.  I'll address this in a moment, but first here is one way that you can use the current structure.

```
const MySlider = () => {
  const currentlang = ... // get the EN or FR object based on your current language

  // an array of all the title texts
  const titles = Object.values(currentlang.page1.section1.titles);

  // an array of all the button texts
  const buttons = Object.values(currentlang.page1.section1.buttons);

  return (
    <Slider>
      {titles.map((title, i) => ( // map through the titles
        <Slide
          title={title}
          buttonText={buttons[i]} // get the button text with the same index -- how do we know this is valid?
          key={i} // i as a key is not great
        />
      ))}
    </Slider>
  );
};
```

With some dummy components so that you can render it:

```
const Slider: React.FC = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

interface SliderProps {
  title: string;
  buttonText: string;
}

const Slide: React.FC<SliderProps> = ({ title, buttonText }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <button>{buttonText}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would recommend grouping the labels by slide rather than by `titles` and `buttons`.  This ensures that titles and buttons match up, allows easy access by the slide key if you want to customize the order, and gives us a unique `key` property for our components.

```
export const EN = {
  page1: {
    section1: {
      slides: {
        sale: {
          title: "title1_name",
          button: "button1_name"
        },
        featured: {
          title: "title2_name",
          button: "button2_name"
        },
        promo: {
          title: "title3_name",
          button: "button3_name"
        },
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```
const MySlider = () => {
  const currentlang = ... // get the EN or FR object based on your current language

  // keyed object of slides
  const slides = currentlang.page1.section1.slides;

  return (
    <Slider>
      {Object.entries(slides).map(
        // Object.entries gives us an array with elements key and value
        ([key, value]) => (
          <Slide
            title={value.title}
            buttonText={value.button}
            key={key}
          />
        )
      )}
    </Slider>
  );
};
```

Key-based approach to allow custom ordering:

```
const MySlider = () => {
  const currentlang = ... // get the EN or FR object based on your current language

  // keyed object of slides
  const slides = currentlang.page1.section1.slides;

  // helper function renders the slide for a given key
  const renderSlide = (key: keyof typeof slides) => {
    const {title, button} = slides[key];
    return (
      <Slide 
        title={title}
        buttonText={button}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Slider>
      {renderSlide("promo")}
      {renderSlide("sale")}
      {renderSlide("featured")}
    </Slider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Great explanation, I will try to follow along. Altough, my translations are coming from i18next useTranslation = so I am using `{t ` something ` }`, should I just create function currentLang instead of that ?

Comment: `currentLang` is just a variable with the language object.  I was setting `const currentLang = EN` to play with it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no option for a .map functions on objects but you can use the `Object.keys` Option.:

```js
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
  myObject[key] *= 2;
});

console.log(myObject);
// => { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }
```

[map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

[Medium MultiLanguage Website](https://medium.com/@ricklee_10931/react-multi-lingual-with-react-i18next-57879f986168)

Comment: But what would be myObject ? Since I have 2 of them (translations EN & FR) I need to use. Could you specify it based on my example ?

Comment: Put some effort into lectures and documentation, added a medium post on how to do a multiLanguage Website in general with i18next.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that though, my translations are working.

Comment: <Slider>{Object.values(currentLang.page1.section1.titles).map(title => (<Slide title={title} />))}</Slider> ?  Higher up in the code (outside render) you would get the currentLang object based on your current language for translations.

Comment: Thank @LindaPaiste for comment, once again closest to the logic I need. I just don't understand where is the title={title} coming from inside the Slider ?

Comment: `Object.values(currentLang.page1.section1.titles)` gives you an array of all the titles in page 1 section 1.  When we call `map` on the array we map from an element of that array to a React component.  The local variable in the `map` callback is the element of the array.  You can call it anything but I am calling it `title` (you set the name in this part: `title =>`). I am assuming that your `Slide` takes a `title` prop so I set the prop `title` on the `Slide` to this `title` variable.

Comment: Useful docs: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)