# Convert Pell.js to Vue component for Customizing

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to convert from pell rich text editor to vue component. I have downloaded pell.js and converted it to vue component but I meet some issues now.
I transfer all datas and methods from pell to vue component.

And I called this.init function in created() method. And it shows that this.defaultActions which defined in datas() is not defined in init functions.

Please give me any advice. Thanks..

Here is my vue component

```js
<template>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>pell</h1>
      <div id="editor" class="pell"></div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px;">
        <h3>Text output:</h3>
        <div id="text-output"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px;">
        <h3>HTML output:</h3>
        <pre id="html-output"></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };
export default {
    data: ()=> ({
        defaultParagraphSeparatorString : 'defaultParagraphSeparator',
        formatBlock : 'formatBlock',
        defaultActions: {
            bold: {
                icon: '<b>B</b>',
                title: 'Bold',
                state: function state() {
                    return this.queryCommandState('bold');
                },
                result: function result() {
                    return this.exec('bold');
                }
            },
            italic: {
                icon: '<i>I</i>',
                title: 'Italic',
                state: function state() {
                    return this.queryCommandState('italic');
                },
                result: function result() {
                    return this.exec('italic');
                }
            },
            underline: {
                icon: '<u>U</u>',
                title: 'Underline',
                state: function state() {
                    return this.queryCommandState('underline');
                },
                result: function result() {
                    return this.exec('underline');
                }
            },
            strikethrough: {
                icon: '<strike>S</strike>',
                title: 'Strike-through',
                state: function state() {
                return this.queryCommandState('strikeThrough');
                },
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('strikeThrough');
                }
            },
            heading1: {
                icon: '<b>H<sub>1</sub></b>',
                title: 'Heading 1',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('formatBlock', '<h1>');
                }
            },
            heading2: {
                icon: '<b>H<sub>2</sub></b>',
                title: 'Heading 2',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('formatBlock', '<h2>');
                }
            },
            paragraph: {
                icon: '&#182;',
                title: 'Paragraph',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('formatBlock', '<p>');
                }
            },
            quote: {
                icon: '&#8220; &#8221;',
                title: 'Quote',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('formatBlock', '<blockquote>');
                }
            },
            olist: {
                icon: '&#35;',
                title: 'Ordered List',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('insertOrderedList');
                }
            },
            ulist: {
                icon: '&#8226;',
                title: 'Unordered List',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('insertUnorderedList');
                }
            },
            code: {
                icon: '&lt;/&gt;',
                title: 'Code',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('formatBlock', '<pre>');
                }
            },
            line: {
                icon: '&#8213;',
                title: 'Horizontal Line',
                result: function result() {
                return this.exec('insertHorizontalRule');
                }
            },
            link: {
                icon: '&#128279;',
                title: 'Link',
                result: function result() {
                var url = window.prompt('Enter the link URL');
                if (url) this.exec('createLink', url);
                }
            },
            image: {
                icon: '&#128247;',
                title: 'Image',
                result: function result() {
                var url = window.prompt('Enter the image URL');
                if (url) this.exec('insertImage', url);
                }
            }
        },

        defaultClasses: {
            actionbar: 'pell-actionbar',
            button: 'pell-button',
            content: 'pell-content',
            selected: 'pell-button-selected'
        },
    }),

    created(){
        console.log("this.defaultActions", this.defaultActions);
        this.init(
            {   
                element: document.getElementById('editor'),
                defaultParagraphSeparator: 'p',
                // actions: [
                //     'bold',
                //     'italic',
                //     'underline',
                //     'strikethrough'
                // ],
                onChange: function (html) {
                    document.getElementById('text-output').innerHTML = html
                    document.getElementById('html-output').textContent = html
                }
            }
        );
    },

    methods:{
        addEventListener(parent, type, listener) {
            return parent.addEventListener(type, listener);
        },
        appendChild(parent, child) {
            return parent.appendChild(child);
        },
        createElement(tag) {
            return document.createElement(tag);
        },
        queryCommandState(command) {
            return document.queryCommandState(command);
        },
        queryCommandValue(command) {
            return document.queryCommandValue(command);
        },
        exec(command) {
            var value = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : null;
            return document.execCommand(command, false, value);
        },

        init(settings){
            Object.keys(this.defaultActions).map(function (action) {
                console.log("action", action)
            });
            var actions = settings.actions ? settings.actions.map(function (action) {
                if (typeof action === 'string') return this.defaultActions[action];
                else if (this.defaultActions[action.name]) return _extends({}, this.defaultActions[action.name], action);
                return action;
            }) : Object.keys(this.defaultActions).map(function (action) {
                console.log("action", action)
                console.log("sss", this.defaultActions)
                // return this.defaultActions[action];
            });

            var classes = _extends({}, this.defaultClasses, settings.classes);

            var defaultParagraphSeparator = settings[this.defaultParagraphSeparatorString] || 'div';

            var actionbar = this.createElement('div');
            actionbar.className = classes.actionbar;
            this.appendChild(settings.element, actionbar);

            var content = settings.element.content = this.createElement('div');
            content.contentEditable = true;
            content.className = classes.content;
            content.oninput = function (_ref) {
                var firstChild = _ref.target.firstChild;

                if (firstChild && firstChild.nodeType === 3) this.exec(this.formatBlock, '<' + defaultParagraphSeparator + '>');else if (content.innerHTML === '<br>') content.innerHTML = '';
                settings.onChange(content.innerHTML);
            };
            content.onkeydown = function (event) {
                if (event.key === 'Enter' && this.queryCommandValue(this.formatBlock) === 'blockquote') {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    return this.exec(this.formatBlock, '<' + defaultParagraphSeparator + '>');
                }, 0);
                }
            };
            this.appendChild(settings.element, content);

            actions.forEach(function (action) {
                var button = this.createElement('button');
                button.className = classes.button;
                button.innerHTML = action.icon;
                button.title = action.title;
                button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                button.onclick = function () {
                return action.result() && content.focus();
                };

                if (action.state) {
                var handler = function handler() {
                    return button.classList[action.state() ? 'add' : 'remove'](classes.selected);
                };
                this.addEventListener(content, 'keyup', handler);
                this.addEventListener(content, 'mouseup', handler);
                this.addEventListener(button, 'click', handler);
                }

                this.appendChild(actionbar, button);
            });

            if (settings.styleWithCSS) this.exec('styleWithCSS');
            this.exec(this.defaultParagraphSeparatorString, defaultParagraphSeparator);

            return settings.element;
        }
    }
}
</script>
    
<style>
    .content {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      #html-output {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      }
      .pell {
  border: 1px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.pell-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px; }

.pell-actionbar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1); }

.pell-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom; }

.pell-button-selected {
  background-color: #F0F0F0; }

</style>
```

Comment: Dont use => function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried but appears same error...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays
there is no issue in answer of this post. I cannot figour out what is problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use arrow functions in the block mapping actions, preserves `this` from the surrounding scope

```js
var actions = settings.actions
  ? settings.actions.map(action => {                            // arrow function here
      if (typeof action === "string") return this.defaultActions[action];
      else if (this.defaultActions[action.name])
        return _extends({}, this.defaultActions[action.name], action);
      return action
    })
  : Object.keys(this.defaultActions).map(action => {            // arrow function here
      console.log("action", action)
      console.log("sss", this.defaultActions);
      // return this.defaultActions[action];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks... It works like charm..
Excuse me, could let me know method that call method in data define part in vue if you have no problem?
I stuck this problem now. :)

Comment: Which bit is it? The next problem I see is with `appendChild` method.

Comment: To fix that one, change the hook from `created()` to `mounted()`, because you can't manipulate the elements until they exist.

Comment: well. yes. you are right. appendchild function has two params - settings.element and content. and setting.element is null because init function is called in created life cycle. I fixed by change it to mounted().

Comment: Next problem is `actions.forEach(function(action) {` change it to `actions.forEach(action => {` for same reason as original question.

Comment: The next  problem maybe call method in data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231674/discussion-between-sammie-and-steve-zodiac).

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, you can also use the sample Vue code given in the [pell repository](https://github.com/jaredreich/pell/blob/master/examples/vue.md)
(or parts thereof, e.g styles)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h6>Editor:</h6>
    <div id="pell" class="pell" />
    <h6>HTML Output:</h6>
    <pre id="pell-html-output"></pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import pell from 'pell'

export default {
  methods: {
    ensureHTTP: str => /^https?:\/\//.test(str) && str || `http://${str}`
  },
  mounted () {
    pell.init({
      element: document.getElementById('pell'),
      onChange: html => {
        window.document.getElementById('pell-html-output').textContent = html
      },
      actions: [
        'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'heading1', 'heading2',
        'paragraph', 'quote', 'olist', 'ulist', 'code', 'line',
        {
          name: 'image',
          result: () => {
            const url = window.prompt('Enter the image URL')
            if (url) pell.exec('insertImage', this.ensureHTTP(url))
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'link',
          result: () => {
            const url = window.prompt('Enter the link URL')
            if (url) pell.exec('createLink', this.ensureHTTP(url))
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.pell {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#pell-html-output {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```