# Create a HTML ordered list on basis of JSON response in React

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I want to create a ordered html list with the JSON response values that I recieve by my backend. I have want to map on the result and per result generate a list item. But when I run this it's only showing 1. with nothing instead of:

1. Started flow version: 1
2. Started flow version: 2

I have the following react code:

```js
const Deployment = (deployment_proces) => {
    Object.values(deployment_proces).map(p => console.log(p))
    const deploymentProcesItems = Object.values(deployment_proces).map(proces => (   
        <li key={proces.id}>
            {proces.message}
        </li>  
    ));
    return (
        <div className='deployment-progress-container'>
            <h6 className='deployment-progress-title'>Deployment progress:</h6>
            <ol className='deployment-progress-list'>
                { deploymentProcesItems }
            </ol>
        </div> 
    )
}
```

My JSON response is as followes:

```json
[
    {
        "code": 200,
        "id": 2251799813688456,
        "message": "Started flow version: 1",
        "name": ""
    },
    {
        "code": 200,
        "id": 2251799813688479,
        "message": "Started flow version: 1",
        "name": ""
    }
]
```

The `deployment_proces` variable is of the type object with as value the above JSON response. So I found a way in [this article](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/76-converting-object-to-array/) to convert a object to an array, because a [object doesn't have a map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays). And when I run the `Object.values(deployment_proces).map(p => console.log(p))` it returns the same JSON as above in the console with length: 2 and **proto**: array(). So it is a array now (right?) and next I want to map on that array using the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=nl) that iterates and creates a `<li key={id}>{message}</li>` per entry.

Any ideas how to fix this /or advice how I can do it better? Because I feel this is way to complex for a simpel iteration over a list.

**EDIT**

My deployment_proces variable value is equal to the return value of the DeployComponent function shown below.

```js
const DeployComponent = async (data, basicAuth) => {
    const response = await ApiCall(constants.ENDPOINTS.DEPLOY_COMPONENT, basicAuth, data);
    if(!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Could not create component.');
    }

    return await HandleCreate(response);
}

const HandleCreate = async response => {
    const result = await response.json();
    if (result) {
        return result;
    } else {
        throw Error('Message invalid response body.');
    }
}
```

And the code where I use the `<Deployment />` component:

```js
const ButtonGroup = ({ data, deployment, basicAuth, doSetDeployment }) => {

  const handleDeployment = async () => {
    if (!data) {
      return
    } 
    var newDeployment = await DeployComponent(data, basicAuth);
    doSetDeployment(newDeployment); 
  }

  const isDisabled = () => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
      //now the data array has blocks check if the diagram has no errors
      return DiagramHasError(data)
    }
    if (!data) {
      return true;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } 

  return (
      <div className='button-group' >
        {deployment ? <Deployment deployment_proces={deployment} /> : null} 
        <Button className={`btn ${isDisabled() ? 'disabled' : ''}`} color='green' text='Deploy diagram' onClick={() => handleDeployment()} disabled={isDisabled()} />
        <Button className={`btn ${isDisabled() ? 'disabled' : ''}`} text='Save' disabled={isDisabled()} />
      </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.drawer.data,
  deployment: state.drawer.deployment,
  basicAuth: state.auth.basicAuth
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  doSetDeployment: setDeployment
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonGroup)
```

Comment: The JSON response already shows an array. If this is the content of `deployment_proces`  .map should work on it directly.

Comment: Yes, I though so too but the `deployment_proces` variable is a object instead of a array for some reason. I've edited my question and added the api function that I use to get the JSON response.

Comment: Oke, I fixed the issue, by changing `{deployment ? <Deployment deployment_proces={deployment} /> : null} ` to `{deployment ? <ol> {deployment.map(proces => <li key={proces.id}>{proces.code} - {proces.message} - {proces.name}</li>)}</ol> : null} `. So I don't make a component and add `deployment_proces` as prop. But I am still so confused why the initial solution is not working properly.