# Merge multiple objects inside an object under an array

Tags: javascript

```
const arrData = [{x: {value: 1}, y: {value: 2}}, {z: {value: 3}}]
```

How can I merge all the objects under each array object as shown below?

```
const arrData = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {z: 3}]
```

Comment: This is no valid `js object`!

Comment: does your table have the same struct always ?

Comment: Assuming the typos in the question are just typos, and the seemingly random conversion of numbers to strings is not actually desired, this should be possible using a couple of nested `map`s (one for objects, another for keys of the objects) along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722/1650337)

Comment: @jns, please check now. Had missed a closing flower bracket.

Comment: someone just doing mass downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arrData = [ {x: {value: 1}, y: {value: 2}}, {z: {value: 3}}]

const res = arrData.map(e =>       // iterate over array
  Object.keys(e)                   // iterate over keys in e (x, y, z)
        .reduce((acc, key) => {    // transform {key: object} into {key: value}
          acc[key] = e[key].value  // transform value object value into value
          return acc               // and merge the keys
        }, {})                     
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

```js
"use strict"
const arrData = [{x: {value: 1}, y: {value: 2}},{z: {value: 3}}];

// (1) mapping all element in arrData
// (2) looping over all entries (e as entry) of element
// (3) return new object 'o' with keys (k) as key and values (object[key].value = v) as values
const res = arrData.map(e => (globalThis.o={}, Object.entries(e).map(([k, v]) => o[k]=v.value.toString()), o))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: something like [{x:1,y:2}, {z:3}], the answer you have posted wraps each object in a new array.

Comment: Check the update!

Comment: throws error in strict mode because of the implicit global variable `o`

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = arrData.map(i => 
Object.entries(i).reduce((acc,el) => {
                                      acc[el[0]]=el[1].value; 
                                      return acc;
                                     } 
                         , {}))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This maps each object in the array to a new one where each of the key-value pairs have been mapped so that the values are plucked out of the original innermost objects.

The re_entry function returns a new function that will convert objects to entries (key - value pairs), uses a supplied function to convert those entries and then creates a new object from those entries.

```js
const arrData = [{x: {value: 1}, y: {value: 2}},{z: {value: 3}}];

const re_entry = (fn) => (obj) => Object.fromEntries( fn(Object.entries(obj)) );
const pluck_value_for_entry = ([k, { value }]) => [k, value];
const re_entry_for_value = re_entry((entries) => entries.map(pluck_value_for_entry));

const res = arrData.map(re_entry_for_value);

console.log(res);
```