# Objects are not valid as a React child when I mapping an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I'm starting react and can't solve my problem. I have an object

```
   modes= {
        "easyMode": {
        "field": 5
        },
        "normalMode": {
        "field": 10
        },
        "hardMode": {
        "field": 15
        }
        }
```

And I need to map this modes(easyMode, normalMode and hardMode), but I know that I can't map an object, only arrays. Right, but this also doesn't work

```
const arrayOfObjects = [{ modes }];

return (
    <ul> {arrayOfObjects.map(mode=> <li key={mode}>{mode} </li>)}</ul>)
```

How I need to do this right?

Comment: If you want to get the keys into an array you can use `Object.keys(modes)` and then map that

Comment: @NickParsons, ok, but in that way I have an error 'arrayOfObjects.keys(modes).map is not a function'

Comment: That is different code to what I suggested above? `Object.keys(modes).map()` is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array with modes keys

```
const modes = {
  easyMode: {
    field: 5,
  },
  normalMode: {
    field: 10,
  },
  hardMode: {
    field: 15,
  },
};

const modesKeys = Object.keys(modes); // ['easyMode','normalMode','hardMode' ]

return (
  <ul> {modesKeys.map(mode => <li key={mode}>{mode}</li>)}</ul>
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really like this variant!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a duplicate question and you can find a complete answer in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829074/6752233)

but as a fast answer, for the objects, you have to iterate like this:

```
Object.keys(modes).map ( mode => {
   console.log(mode,modes[mode]) // you can access the values like this
})
```