# nested array object property return undefined typeError in react redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

i want to show the post detail in frontend. my api is showing the postdetail like below captured in postman:

```
"message": "Posts fetched successfully!",
    "posts": {
        "_id": "61f05f676793d49f466e7aaa",
        "title": "Liberal Arts Student Sample",
        "content": "The three-page.",
        "creator": {
            "_id": "61cd99efa0b8d616a7a53ce1",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-30T11:37:19.041Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T14:35:48.801Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "bio": "user bio",
            "name": "username"
        },
        "Comments": [],
        "created": "2022-01-25T20:36:55.095Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-25T20:36:55.096Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-01-25T20:36:55.096Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

i want to exhibit this post detail in frontend and here is the code:

```
export default function PostDetail() {
    const { postId } = useParams();
    const post = useSelector((state) => state.post)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { title, content,creator, created } = post;
    const fetchPostDetail = async (id) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/articles/post/${id}`, { post })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        dispatch(selectedPost(response.data.posts));
              }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPostDetail(postId)
    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Post Detail</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                <i>posted in {created}</i>
                 <li>Created by {creator.map((m,i)=>(
<b key={i}>{m.name}</b>
                 ))}</li> 
                <p>{content}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

There are three errors:

1. Uncaught TypeError: creator is undefined
2. The above error occurred in the  component:
3. Uncaught TypeError: creator is undefined

if i mute the

Created by {creator.map((m,i)=>(
{m.name}
                 ))}

then it shows the post detail without post author name. but i want to show the author name.

how can i solve that?
thank you in advance

Comment: `"creator": {` seems to indicate that `creator` is an **Object**. Not sure if the `.map()` is applicable to an Object. Please try `creator.name` instead.

Comment: i did,but it is showing same error.

Comment: Okay, are you able to add `console.log(post)`, just after `const { title, content,creator, created } = post;` and share the result?

Comment: It’s solved. I had to use   {creator && <li> Created by :{creator.name}</li> and it worked smoothly. Thanx any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first time when the component will mount, the value of the creator will be undefined. You need to add a check before getting the nested value.

```
<div>
  <h1>Post Detail </h1>
  <div>
    <h2>{title} </h2>
    <i> posted in {created} </i>
    {creator && <li> Created by :{creator.name}</li>}
    <p> {content} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note: One thing more, Creator is not an array. it is an Object. So you cant map the object. In case it is an array, You have to make above check in that case too.**

Comment: it worked man, thanx....freaking coooool. I have a question why should I use the condition? I mean should the useEffect suppose to fetch data at a same time??

Answer (score 1):

Here, creator is an Object. Whereas .map function is for Array.
To map an Object you can check:
[map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: i have tried <div>
  <h1>Post Detail</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <i>posted in {created}</i>
    <li><b>Created by {creator.name}</b></li> 
    <p>{content}</p>
  </div>
</div> but it shows the same error of Uncaught TypeError: creator is undefined. but when i put console.log(response.data.posts.creator.name) in useEffect after the dispatch it shows the creator name in devtools. what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have provided your object with creater,

```
"creator": {
  "_id": "61cd99efa0b8d616a7a53ce1",
  "createdAt": "2021-12-30T11:37:19.041Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T14:35:48.801Z",
  "__v": 0,
  "bio": "user bio",
  "name": "username"
},
```

`map` method is only works with Array. But Here You have used with Object

```
<div>
   <h1>Post Detail</h1>
   <div>
     <h2>{title}</h2>
     <i>posted in {created}</i>
     <li>Created by {creator.map((m,i)=>(
         <b key={i}>{m.name}</b>
         ))}
     </li> 
     <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can replace Your code with

```
<div>
  <h1>Post Detail</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <i>posted in {created}</i>
    <li><b>Created by {creator.name}</b></li> 
    <p>{content}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried <div>
  <h1>Post Detail</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <i>posted in {created}</i>
    <li><b>Created by {creator.name}</b></li> 
    <p>{content}</p>
  </div>
</div> but it shows the same error of Uncaught TypeError: creator is undefined. but when i put console.log(response.data.posts.creator.name) in useEffect after the dispatch it shows the creator name in devtools. what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

make sure the post object contains the "creator" key, and you don't need map() if the state looks exactly like the API response. If you could show how the state looks that will reveal more of the issue.

Comment: i have tried <div>
  <h1>Post Detail</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <i>posted in {created}</i>
    <li><b>Created by {creator.name}</b></li> 
    <p>{content}</p>
  </div>
</div> but it shows the same error of Uncaught TypeError: creator is undefined. but when i put console.log(response.data.posts.creator.name) in useEffect after the dispatch it shows the creator name in devtools. what is going wrong?