# How do I .map() through data that is layered?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I'm learning about `fetch()` and am struggling to overcome an issue. I have some JSON data I am fetching, but the key is the "parent" of each item, eg it looks like:

```
 products
    p1
      description:"Lorem Ipsum"
      name:"some product"
      price:9.99
    p2
      description:"Dolar sit amet"
      name:"another product"
      price:15.5
```

I'd like to `.map()` this data into a new array, as such:

```
  const newData= data.results.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name,
      description: item.description,
      price: item.price
    };
  });
```

But I don't understand how I can iterate through each item and save it's ID without a key.

Would anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: The data you listed doesn't have a `id` or `title`, just a `name`. Can you post a sample the actual data as JSON in the format you expect?

Comment: Sorry - typo - it is `name` not `title`. I am still not sure how to get the ids (p1, p2)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: So you basically want to use `p1` in the `map` right?

Comment: your argument to `map` is `mydata` then what is `item`?

Comment: @mousetail yes, thats right. Ultimately I want to use the data in a React component like: `products.map(meal => <Product key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} description={item.description} price={item.price} />)`

Comment: @AlanOmar - sorry mistake. I fixed it. Just trying to keep my company anonymous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: It's still hard to understand what you are trying to achieve here, if you could post some pseudo input and the desired output it would be a great help for us to help you.

Comment: Is `products` an array of objects or an object of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function:

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs. This is the same as iterating with a for...in loop, except that a for...in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.

```
Object.entries(data.products).map(([key, value]) => ({
    id: key,
    name: value.name,
    description: value.description,
    price: value.price
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since what you have posted looks like object, rather than array. You have to first transform it into an array. I would suggest using `Object.entries()`

```
Object.entries(products).map(([key, value])=> {
 return {
   id: key, 
   name: value.name,
   description: value.description,
   price: value.price
 }
})
```