# How to Map an object's values regardless of its keys, and strongly type it (like Array<T>.map)

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, functional-programming

I'm in ES7/ES8, I want to know how to map an object's values, regardless of its keys (like Array.map).

I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

But :

- I am forced to map also the whole object, not the just value
- I also want it to give a strongly typed type inference when assigning to a variable.
- (If possible in a functional coding style)

```
// === TO MODIFY ===
type AnyObjectKeys = string | number;
type AnyObject<
  Values,
  Keys extends AnyObjectKeys = AnyObjectKeys,
  > = Record<Keys, Values>;

type MapperFunc<T> = (
  value: [AnyObjectKeys, T],
  index: number,
  array: [AnyObjectKeys, T][],
) => unknown

/**
 * map an object's values, like Array<T>.map
 * but can also access its key with another signature
 */
const objMapper =
  <AnyObjectValues>(object: AnyObject<AnyObjectValues>) =>
    (func: MapperFunc<AnyObjectValues>) =>
      Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(object).map(func));
// === TO MODIFY ===

const getAverage = (arr: number[]) =>
  arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length

// BASE OBJECT
const curvesPointsByDynamicKeys = {
  ['a']: {
    x: [3, 4, 1],
    y: [6, 1, 4],
    z: [3, 9, 0],
  },
  ['b']: {
    x: [2, 1, 0],
    y: [9, 3, 3],
    z: [4, 6, 0],
  },
  // ...
};

// EXPECTED USAGE 1 (with key access)
const curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys = objMapper(curvesPointsByDynamicKeys)
  (
    ([key, { x, y, z }]) => {
      return {
        id: `curve-${key}-${x.length}-${y.length}-${z.length}`,
        averageX: getAverage(x),
        averageY: getAverage(y),
        averageZ: getAverage(z),
      }
    }
  );

// EXPECTED USAGE 2 (without key access)
const curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys2 = objMapper(curvesPointsByDynamicKeys)
  (
    ({ x, y, z }) => {
      return {
        averageX: getAverage(x),
        averageY: getAverage(y),
        averageZ: getAverage(z),
      }
    }
  );

// EXPECTED RESULT 1 :
// {
//   ['a']: {
//     id: '...',
//     averageX: 2.6666666666666665,
//     averageY: 3.6666666666666665,
//     averageZ: 4,
//   },
//   ['b']: {
//     id: '...',
//     averageX: 1,
//     averageY: 5,
//     averageZ: 3.3333333333333335,
//   },
//   // ...
// }
console.log(curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys)

// EXPECTED RESULT 2 :
// {
//   ['a']: {
//     averageX: 2.6666666666666665,
//     averageY: 3.6666666666666665,
//     averageZ: 4,
//   },
//   ['b']: {
//     averageX: 1,
//     averageY: 5,
//     averageZ: 3.3333333333333335,
//   },
//   // ...
// }
console.log(curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys2)

// NOT EXPECTED RESULT :
// {
//   averageX: 1,
//   averageY: 5,
//   averageZ: 3.3333333333333335,
// }
```

Comment: I think [this approach](//tsplay.dev/m3XPjW) is the closest to what you're looking for.  First, I assume `x` instead of `averageX` in the result is just a typo. Second, there's no way to have your mapper function *decide* whether its first argument will be a tuple of key-value pairs or just the value. The *caller* decides what to pass, and it can't probe the callback function to figure out what it expects (function parameter types are just part of the TS static type system and do not exist at runtime); you'll have a much better time passing a consistent set of parameters always. ...

Comment: ... If that approach meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think that's the closest approach that I want, and I would not refuse some explanations !

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original version where the callback passed to the result of `objMapper()` *either* accepts a single parameter of a key-value [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), *or* a single parameter of just the value type, is not going to work.  At runtime, it's essentially impossible to inspect a function and understand what type of parameter it accepts.  Such information doesn't really exist at runtime.  So the implementation of `objMapper()` would never know whether to pass `[key, value]` or just `value` to the callback.

Instead, we can write `objMapper()` so that it always passes both `value` and `key` as two separate arguments to the callback.  If the callback cares about both `value` and `key`, it should use them, like `(value, key) => {}`.  Otherwise, if it only wants `value` then it should only look at the first argument, like `(value) => {}`.  This is acceptable, since [functions with fewer parameters are assignable to functions that take more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).

---

Here's what that looks like:

```
const objMapper =
    <K extends PropertyKey, VI>(obj: { [P in K]: VI }) =>
        <VO,>(func: (v: VI, k: K) => VO) =>
            Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(obj).map(
                    ([k, v]) => [k, func(v as any, k as any)])
            ) as { [P in K]: VO };
```

The call signature is essentially that you pass `objMapper` an `obj` of a type whose keys are of the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K`, and whose values are of the generic type `VI` (the "input value" type).  This returns another generic function which takes a callback `func` of type `(v: VI, k: K) => VO`, meaning it accepts both the input value `v` and the key `k`, and returns a value of the generic type `VO`, the "output value" type.  And the return type of this function is something whose keys are of generic type `K`, and whose values are of the generic type `VO`.

The implementation is using [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to turn `obj` into an array of entries, [the `map()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the value with the `func` callback, and [the `Object.fromEntries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to turn the entry array back into an object.  (The compiler can't verify that this actually satisfies the call signature, so I used a bunch of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress errors.  I presume you care more about the compiler verifying type safety for *callers* of `objMapper` than you do for the *implementer*.)

---

Let's test it out on your example code, noting that the callback parameters either look like `({x, y, z}, key) => {}` or like `({x, y, z}) => {}`:

```
const curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys = objMapper(curvesPointsByDynamicKeys)(
    ({ x, y, z }, key) => {
        return {
            id: `curve-${key}-${x.length}-${y.length}-${z.length}`,
            averageX: getAverage(x),
            averageY: getAverage(y),
            averageZ: getAverage(z),
        }
    }
);
console.log(curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys);
/* {
  "a": {
    "id": "curve-a-3-3-3",
    "averageX": 2.6666666666666665,
    "averageY": 3.6666666666666665,
    "averageZ": 4
  },
  "b": {
    "id": "curve-b-3-3-3",
    "averageX": 1,
    "averageY": 5,
    "averageZ": 3.3333333333333335
  }
}  */
```

and

```
const curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys2 = objMapper(curvesPointsByDynamicKeys)
    (
        ({ x, y, z }) => {
            return {
                averageX: getAverage(x),
                averageY: getAverage(y),
                averageZ: getAverage(z),
            }
        }
    );

console.log(curvesAveragePointsByDynamicKeys2)
/* {
  "a": {
    "averageX": 2.6666666666666665,
    "averageY": 3.6666666666666665,
    "averageZ": 4
  },
  "b": {
    "averageX": 1,
    "averageY": 5,
    "averageZ": 3.3333333333333335
  }
} 
*/
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAsgQwA7oKYCcYF4AoGEmAHgGkYsAPKLMAEwhgAUcRscoBPCrHgBoYANQCSAPgAUCRAC4YAbxgBtVjACWYGBQC6C8TAC+ASgITipK2REB5QdIBmAVzDAFUgG4GxwgNYKFGb4EqK2wRZWUaS2SFjAUAB0jhwAtgCiYFA4GlgQUpbRRTCxiPFJDNm5+bImiakYBcXNpFIqfsKeuhGqHTAubl4wqCyoYEIwfsOj4ybdhc1mI0qq6lo6+mHGANyEhKCQsADmWFAAgp64qCcEMFKoODgKYM6p8Lgq3eYLDziJOFhGM5gFgpPdhPAeqgYABqGDwYQABjMAHpho9EgAbBhHKAACz2B2gMGAzhwlwgrBAWigEAAQjwACI8MCoVIaYD8HgsfBKH4KRQLKw0BQqADMwgALMIAIy6QRC0g8UUANllUvlipIAC9RRKYABOJGaqxGBVWeACrUwEWqABM6pgiJNRWVqiNMH1Ypd0V1qmlMDVTp9xnNpBRaMSUcIRl2+3AxNJ5LyFyuJypNPpTJZbI5XJ5cCQaEwuCkSYpGayWeZrPZnIEEBMTVayhowgm2tDkwEPUFxQBUDJ2j7LU0jAUAANy1gALQAEkUfgERnnihoWJx+JXC54G7AuLx28U2r3B6ME7DLVQlxw1ywAA0FCdzje71IaCZL81r2msABNJ9TlTW8TikHhP2tKwfxArAAC1AJfX8pG1CDiiMBZ0JMXYiRAbEsRAI4yzJClgLvStaQZGtc3rbksMIFEACo+RIAAiVAWKtKwWI0RgOJgFjpxnVAZzFESRJYr82NfE57z4u1EhVRSlOUlSAFZJOgu8-z4sUFJU-SlPUhYpN-WC+MlSwzUsFj4D4kdWJ4viBOI2d4DE0SxQk4zNJkviZQ06T-z4oyuJ8uCdMSMUouimLYtUyyYxIBiUUJBNYGnCBSPTakq0onM63zO1blkYsuCI5NKRyijs1rPMGxMBZm2iKRW3bYRO1McxmNHAch260dSDCx8YGfLLQQ-L8BrCgCRqAwKwNQgbBsC+DZsQmDkMWlp0LQhY6PjSBcKwfDCIysbyOrfK6u5O0GsY7q2Ls7zAtkhR5IMj6QtIEyYO0hRdI+gyvtYsKzIUCySCs1jbM476hr8gLfz+mBgf40GItizGYviyHEuIZLCCAA)