# find the odd value in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object in JavaScript and I would like to find the one value that is an odd number, then return that value's corresponding key. For example:

```
const myObject = {
                   'a': 4,
                   'b': 6,
                   'c': 7,
                   'd': 8
                  }
```

From this, I would like to return 'c'. The following is what I have attempted, but I get an error.

```js
const myObject = {
  'a': 4,
  'b': 6,
  'c': 7,
  'd': 8
}
myObject.forEach((i) => {
  if (counts.value[i] % 2 === 0)
    return counts.key[i];
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays. I believe this question will help you solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the `array` of `myObject` keys and use `find` to get the value that is odd.

```js
const myObject = {
   'a': 4,
   'b': 6,
   'c': 7,
   'd': 8
}

let key = Object.keys(myObject).find((key) => myObject[key] % 2)

console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
const myObject = {
  'a': 4,
  'b': 6,
  'c': 7,
  'd': 8
};
const res = Object.keys(myObject).find(k => myObject[k] % 2 !== 0);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get object values to array and filter the odd values from the values array

```js
const myObject = { 'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 8};
const valuesArr = Object.values(myObject);
const result = valuesArr.filter((value) =>  {
   if ((value % 2) !== 0) {
      return value;
   }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the result in **single iteration** and return the **odd value key.**

```js
const myObject = { 'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 8};
let result = '';

for(const key in myObject) {
  if((myObject[key] % 2) !== 0) {
      result = key;
      break;
  }
}

console.log(result);
//return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const myObject = {
                       'a': 4,
                       'b': 6,
                       'c': 7,
                       'd': 8
                      };
    Object.keys(myObject).filter((each) => {
    if( myObject[each] % 2 === 1){ 
    return each;
    }
        );
```