# Why is map stopping rendering of a heading in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still slightly confused about map. When I comment out the map my h2 renders, what am I doing wrong? Yes I would still like to use fetch. I need to understand what I'm doing wrong before I add more depth to it.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function SearchAPI() {

    const [cocktail, setCocktail] = useState()
    

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita')
        .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
            setCocktail(data.drinks[0])
            console.log(cocktail)
            
           
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`error ${err}`)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <h2>here is your drink</h2>
            {cocktail.map((element) => {
                return <h2>{element.strDrink}</h2>
                
                
            })}
        </>
    )
}
```

When I comment out the function it renders.

Comment: The h2 is outside of the map, so makes sense that it's rendered when you comment the map.

Comment: is cocktail still an array in render? After you update it with setCocktail

Answer (score 0):

> When I comment out the map my h2 renders, what am I doing wrong?

The `h2` is outside the `map()`, so if the `cocktail` is empty, you'll still render the `h2`.

---

You probably only want to render the `h2` if `cocktail` has some data.

You can add a default value to the state (`useState({})`) and then use `Object.keys(coctail).length === 0` to check if there are any values in the object.

Then using `(condition) ? <>content with data</> : <>loading</>` to render the `h2` and `map()` or a loading message.

Where you [loop over the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays) to render all the info

---

Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const SearchAPI = () => {

    const [cocktail, setCocktail] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setCocktail(data.drinks[0]) )
        .catch(err => console.log(`error ${err}`))
    }, [])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {
                (Object.keys(cocktail).length > 0) 
                  ? (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <h1>here is your drink</h1>
                            {Object.keys(cocktail).map((key, index) => (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <div class='row'>
                                        <h3>{key}</h3>
                                        <em>{cocktail[key]}</em>
                                    </div>
                                </React.Fragment>
                            ))}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                  : <em>{'Loading data'}</em>
            }            
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<SearchAPI />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.row {
    width: 50vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: There is nearly never any value in asking for a reason for a comment. If the voter did not provide any feedback when voting, they wish to remain anonymous, as is their right. That is a key design feature of voting on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use the `map()` method on an object, which won't work. The `map()` method is an array method that can only be used on arrays.

If you're trying to access data from an object, you'll need to use dot notation to access the individual object properties. For example, if you have an object `cocktail` and you're trying to access the `strdrink` property, you would do it like this: `cocktail.strdrink`.

If you have set `cocktail` to `data.drinks[0]`, this will access the first object in the drinks array.

Change this:

```
    {cocktail.map((element) => {
      return <h2>{element.strDrink}</h2>
    })}
```

to that:

```
    {cocktail && <h2>{cocktail.strDrink}</h2>}
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [cocktail, setCocktail] = useState()
    
    useEffect(() => {
   fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita')
        .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
            setCocktail(data.drinks[0])
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`error ${err}`)
        })
    }, [])
   
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>here is your drink</h2>
            {cocktail && <h2>{cocktail.strDrink}</h2>}
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```