# How to retrieve dynamic JSON keys where value is true?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I have the below JSON response:

```
{
  "A":{"Option1":true,"Option2":true,"Option3":false}
  "B":{"OptionX":true,"OptionY":true,"OptionZ":false}
 }
```

I want to get the following values in a string: Option1, Option2, OptionX, OptionY

I have tried the below but with no luck:

```
  Array.from(this.model).forEach(child => {
    console.log(child, 'child name')
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap()` with `filter()` where you [`map` over each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays) using `Object.keys()`

```js
const data = {
  "A": {"Option1":true,"Option2":true,"Option3":false},
  "B": {"OptionX":true,"OptionY":true,"OptionZ":false}
};
 
const res = Object.values(data).flatMap(o => Object.keys(o).filter(k => o[k]));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (const record of Object.values(json)) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(record)) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(key);
    }
  }
}

// or

const keys = Object
  .values(json)
  .map(record => Object
    .entries(record)
    .filter(([key, value]) => value)
    .map(([key]) => key)
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const obj = {
  "A": {
    "Option1": true,
    "Option2": true,
    "Option3": false
  },
  "B": {
    "OptionX": true,
    "OptionY": true,
    "OptionZ": false
  }
}

const result = Object.values(obj).flatMap(o => Object.entries(o).filter(([key, value]) => value).map(([key]) => key))

console.log(result)
```