# Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Actual code:

```
const genreOptions = [{{ genreOptions | json_encode | raw }}].map((type , label) => ({value: type, label: label}));
```

Debugging code:

```
            const genreOptions = {
                "Horror": "Korku",
                "Comedy": "Komedi\u0103 Filmi",
                "Action": "Aksiyon",
                "Drama": "Drama"
            }.map((type,label)=>({
                value: type,
                label: label
            }));
```

Im getting the following error from above code:

**Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.map is not a function"**

Array Dump from Backend Now:

```
array:4 [▼
  "Horror" => "Korku"
  "Comedy" => "Komedi\u0103 Filmi"
  "Action" => "Aksiyon"
  "Drama" => "Drama"
]
```

Array Dump  Backend Before Modification:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "Horror"
  1 => "Comedy"
  2 => "Action"
  3 => "Drama"
]
```

We are trying now to translate the website and therefore I put the actual Words as keys in array instead of 0,1,2,3... and then the translations.

But we're getting *".map is not a function error [...]"* .map() is used only on arrays and we're surprised why the new version isn't well received as array.

I added Square brackets [] and the error was gone but the result was not as we've had expected it.

I would like Comedy to be assigned to "value" and Korku to "label".

Comment: That's not an array. Arrays have implicit keys (0, 1, 2, ...), and `.map()` is an Array method.

Comment: Isnt it an associated array? I added [] around then the error was gone but it didnt work as I expected... any hints to make it work?

Comment: you're talking about a Map or Dictionary.  There is only one type of [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JavaScript. As the second bullet point states "JavaScript arrays are not associative arrays"

Comment: Okay so previously it was an array but after the keys modification it became an Object(dictionary). How can I use its components and assign values?

Comment: @Anarkie It's called an associative array in PHP. In JS, arrays are lists (numeric sequential indexes) and what's called "associative arrays" in PHP are just objects in JS.

Comment: There are many ways to iterate an Object in JS.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722/6225326) is a pretty good answer going over multiple methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`genreOptions` is an object with key/value, you could use `Object.entries` then `map` to get the expected output :

```js
const genreOptions = Object.entries({
        "Horror": "Korku",
        "Comedy": "Komedi\u0103 Filmi",
        "Action": "Aksiyon",
        "Drama": "Drama"
    }).map(
    ([type, label])=>({ 
        value: type,
        label: label
    })
)
```

Comment: You deserve a medal sir!

Comment: @hakre why is it wrong?

Comment: @Anarkie: Not why, but only for which part; see the last edit.